# Responding with a JSON object in Node.js (converting object/array to JSON string)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a newb to back-end code and I'm trying to create a function that will respond to me a JSON string. I currently have this from an example

```
function random(response) {
  console.log("Request handler 'random was called.");
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});

  response.write("random numbers that should come in the form of json");
  response.end();
}
```

This basically just prints the string "random numbers that should come in the form of JSON". What I want this to do is respond with a JSON string of whatever numbers. Do I need to put a different content-type? should this function pass that value to another one say on the client side?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: res.json({"Key": "Value"});

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Using [res.json](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json) with Express:

```
function random(response) {
  console.log("response.json sets the appropriate header and performs JSON.stringify");
  response.json({ 
    anObject: { item1: "item1val", item2: "item2val" }, 
    anArray: ["item1", "item2"], 
    another: "item"
  });
}
```

Alternatively:

```
function random(response) {
  console.log("Request handler random was called.");
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
  var otherArray = ["item1", "item2"];
  var otherObject = { item1: "item1val", item2: "item2val" };
  var json = JSON.stringify({ 
    anObject: otherObject, 
    anArray: otherArray, 
    another: "item"
  });
  response.end(json);
}
```

Answer (score 79):

```
var objToJson = { };
objToJson.response = response;
response.write(JSON.stringify(objToJson));
```

If you `alert(JSON.stringify(objToJson))` you will get `{"response":"value"}`

Comment: Beware that res.write(JSON.stringify()) still wait for you to "end" the response. (res.end()) ; express .json() to this for you

Answer (score 25):

You have to use the `JSON.stringify()` function included with the V8 engine that node uses.

```
var objToJson = { ... };
response.write(JSON.stringify(objToJson));
```

**Edit:** As far as I know, [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/) has officially registered a MIME type for JSON as `application/json` in [RFC4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt).  It is also is listed in the [Internet Media Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267546/correct-http-header-for-json-file).

Comment: Should the content-type header also be set to application/json or something like that? What is best practice for this?

Comment: Yes, to make it a valid response the client will understand. Add: res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}) before

Answer (score 13):

Per [JamieL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214220/jamiel)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23198978/585552) to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696240/proper-way-to-return-json-using-node-or-express):

> Since Express.js 3x the response object has a json() method which sets
>   all the headers correctly for you.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> res.json({"foo": "bar"});
> ```

Comment: How can I do the same with a JSON file?

Comment: dont forget res.end() if you use this, I needed it

Answer (score 3):

in express there may be application-scoped JSON formatters.

after looking at express\lib\response.js, I'm using this routine:

```
function writeJsonPToRes(app, req, res, obj) {
    var replacer = app.get('json replacer');
    var spaces = app.get('json spaces');
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    var partOfResponse = JSON.stringify(obj, replacer, spaces)
        .replace(/\u2028/g, '\\u2028')
        .replace(/\u2029/g, '\\u2029');
    var callback = req.query[app.get('jsonp callback name')];
    if (callback) {
        if (Array.isArray(callback)) callback = callback[0];
        res.set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
        var cb = callback.replace(/[^\[\]\w$.]/g, '');
        partOfResponse = 'typeof ' + cb + ' === \'function\' && ' + cb + '(' + partOfResponse + ');\n';
    }
    res.write(partOfResponse);
}
```

Comment: Is this for sending back javascript functions? Am i getting this right? And why would you do that? Just curious

Answer (score 0):

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');

http.createServer((req,res)=>{

    const parseObj =  url.parse(req.url,true);
    const users = [{id:1,name:'soura'},{id:2,name:'soumya'}]

    if(parseObj.pathname == '/user-details' && req.method == "GET") {
        let Id = parseObj.query.id;
        let user_details = {};
        users.forEach((data,index)=>{
            if(data.id == Id){
                user_details = data;
            }
        })
        res.writeHead(200,{'x-auth-token':'Auth Token'})
        res.write(JSON.stringify(user_details)) // Json to String Convert
        res.end();
    }
}).listen(8000);
```

I have used the above code in my existing project.

Answer (score -2):

The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

```
response.write(JSON.stringify({ x: 5, y: 6 }));
```

[know more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)