# Java: http request, print headers and parse json

Tags: java, json, http-headers, httprequest

I have no knowledge of Java, but a collaborator is writing code and attempts to parse a JSON response that the server that I am writing is providing. I also created [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696240/proper-way-to-return-json-using-node-or-express) question yesterday trying to see if there was a problem on my end. However, the problem still remains.

So, can someone give me some simple code of what needs to be written in Java in order to make an http request to a server (say http://www.google.com) print the headers of the response and moreover parse a json object that is returned? Or at least, which functions should I be using and which libraries I should include in the source code. I want to believe that I will figure it out after that point.

I am totally clueless how to do that and what sort of libraries I need in java. Honestly, I do not know java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step would be looking into the Servlet specification of the Java language. I would recommend the Google GSON library for parsing JSON.