# What does body-parser do with express?

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I don't understand why we need `body-parser` in an Express application, as we can get data without using `body-parser`.
And what does it do actually and how?

Comment: in order to read HTTP POST data , we  have to use "body-parser" node module.

body-parser is a piece of express middleware that  reads a form's input and stores it as a javascript  object accessible through `req.body`

Comment: With express you can read any data inside HTTP request, such as headers  `req.headers` (array), you can read the body of the http packet as `req.body` explained by @CleanCrispCode and you can read as query parameter `req.query.variable`, It helps since express automatically transforms the request in javascript objects

Comment: @refactor -- this might be *one* of the many reasons we *have to use* body parser, but it doesn't say what it does, i.e. that HTTP request and response objects are streams and that they're not 'readable' as single object like ``res.body`` without the entire stream being buffered into ``res.body`` first.

Comment: With Express version 4.16+ they have included their own version of body-parser built in so you don't have to pull in this package.

Comment: Also see [You don't need body-parser in Express 4.16+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63999686/11667949)

Answer (score 383):

**Edit: in 2019-april-2**
in express@4.16.0 the body-parser middleware is included in express, so you don't need to install body-parser separately anymore. [for more details see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47232318/8784518)

**OLD:**

To handle `HTTP POST` requests in **Express.js** version 4 and above, you need to install the middleware module called `body-parser`.

**`body-parser` extracts the entire body portion of an incoming request stream and exposes it on `req.body`.**

The middleware was a part of Express.js earlier but now you have to install it separately.

This `body-parser` module parses the JSON, buffer, string and URL encoded data submitted using `HTTP POST` request. Install `body-parser` using NPM as shown below.

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

Comment: This is quite possibly the lamest thing ever. Why would Express core devs make it incredibly difficult for newcomers to get on board by making them install additional middleware for the most common use cases in web development?

Comment: @elmt if you want something with opinions, try sails.js

Comment: Do `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))` and `app.use(bodyParser.json())` automatically invoke `next()`?

Comment: @user1063287 yes it does. `urlencoded()` and `json()` are actually middleware factories that return a middleware function which invokes `next()`

Comment: It is not lame @elmt, node is not only for web, it can be used on desktop, mobile, etc, and in these cases it is not a required module. Node can adapt to your application without any liability

Comment: @fnaquira - You're confused. This is about express not node.

Comment: Maybe Express isn't for newcomers?  <ducks>

Comment: @elmt actually this is something that is happening to other frameworks such as react native too! and there is a good reason for it. we should try to lighten the core framework as much as possible. this way, someone that needs a specific functionality can easily add it to the project and the one who doesn't need it can have the lightest version of his app

Comment: @elmt has a point. Why not just include that within express rather than keeping it as a separate middleware? Also, body-parser doesn't seem to work as a standalone library which you can use in apps written in non-express frameworks/vanilla nodeJs apps so I'm not sure what they've achieved by doing this.

Comment: how to check if body parser installed or not

Comment: @PoojaGupta in node_modules

Comment: @elmt Express version 4.16+ include their own body-parser implementation in the default Express package so there is no need for you to download another dependency.

Comment: @MohamedBenHEnda - i'm confused, the [official Express docs on body-parser](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) don't mention anything about `body-parser` being bundled with `Express`, and they provide usage instructions as `npm install body-parser` and `var bodyParser = require('body-parser')`.  if this is not correct, and you don't need to install anything 'extra', how do you call `body-parser` and use it?

Answer (score 122):

Yes we can work without `body-parser`. When you don't use that you get the raw request, and your body and headers are not in the root object of request parameter . You will have to individually manipulate all the fields.

Or you can use `body-parser`, as the express team is maintaining it .

What body-parser can do for you: It simplifies the request.
How to use it: Here is example:

Install `npm install body-parser --save`

This how to use body-parser in express:

```
const express = require('express'),
      app = express(),
      bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// support parsing of application/json type post data
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//support parsing of application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Link.

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser.

And then you can get body and headers in root request object. Example

```
app.post("/posturl",function(req,res,next){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("response");
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the info, can you post a code example without body parser?

Comment: @llyas you can check some blog https://itnext.io/how-to-handle-the-post-request-body-in-node-js-without-using-a-framework-cd2038b93190. Here they have use http module of node.js , same way you can use in express also , inside `app.post("/posturl",function(req,res,next){`

Answer (score 77):

The answer [here](https://www.quora.com/What-exactly-does-body-parser-do-with-express-js-and-why-do-I-need-it) explain it very detailed and brilliantly, the answer contains:

> In short; *body-parser* extracts the entire body portion of an incoming request stream and exposes it on `req.body` as something easier to interface with. You don't need it per se, because you could do all of that yourself. However, it will most likely do what you want and save you the trouble.
>
> ---
>
> To go a little more in depth; body-parser gives you a middleware which uses [nodejs/zlib](https://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html) to unzip the incoming request data if it's zipped and [stream-utils/raw-body](https://github.com/stream-utils/raw-body) to await the full, raw contents of the request body before "parsing it" (this means that if you weren't going to use the request body, you just wasted some time).
>
> After having the raw contents, body-parser will parse it using one of four strategies, depending on the specific middleware you decided to use:
>
> - [bodyParser.raw()](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserrawoptions): Doesn't actually parse the body, but just exposes the buffered up contents from before in a [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) on `req.body`.
> - [bodyParser.text()](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparsertextoptions): Reads the buffer as plain text and exposes the resulting string on req.body.
> - [bodyParser.urlencoded()](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions): Parses the text as URL encoded data (which is how browsers tend to send form data from regular forms set to POST) and exposes the resulting object (containing the keys and values) on `req.body`. For comparison; in PHP all of this is automatically done and exposed in `$_POST`.
> - [bodyParser.json()](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions): Parses the text as JSON and exposes the resulting object on `req.body`.
>
> Only after setting the `req.body` to the desirable contents will it call the next middleware in the stack, which can then access the request data without having to think about how to unzip and parse it.

You can refer to *body-parser* [github](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) to read their documentation, it contains information regarding its working.

Answer (score 73):

Let’s try to keep this least technical.

Let’s say you are sending a html form data to node-js server i.e. you made a request to the server. The server file would receive your request under a request object. Now by logic, if you console log this request object in your server file you should see your form data some where in it, which could be extracted then, but whoa ! you actually don’t !

So, where is our data ? How will we extract it if its not only present in my request.

Simple explanation to this is http sends your form data in bits and pieces which are intended to get assembled as they reach their destination. So how would you extract your data.

But, why take this pain of every-time manually parsing your data for chunks and assembling it. Use something called “body-parser” which would do this for you.

body-parser parses your request and converts it into a format from which you can easily extract relevant information that you may need.

For example, let’s say you have a sign-up form at your frontend. You are filling it, and requesting server to save the details somewhere.

Extracting username and password from your request goes as simple as below if you use body-parser.

```
var loginDetails = {    
    username : request.body.username,    
    password : request.body.password    
};
```

So basically, body-parser parsed your incoming request, assembled the chunks containing your form data, then created this body object for you and filled it with your form data.

Answer (score 16):

#### History:

Earlier versions of Express used to have a lot of middleware bundled with it. `bodyParser` was one of the middleware that came with it. When Express 4.0 was released they decided to remove the bundled middleware from Express and make them separate packages instead. The syntax then changed from `app.use(express.json())` to `app.use(bodyParser.json())` after installing the `bodyParser` module.

`bodyParser` was added back to Express in release 4.16.0, because people wanted it bundled with Express like before. That means you don't have to use `bodyParser.json()` anymore if you are on the latest release. You can use `express.json()` instead.

The release history for 4.16.0 is [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/releases/tag/4.16.0) for those who are interested, and the pull request is [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/pull/3423).

Okay, back to the point,

#### Implementation:

All you need to add is just add,

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
```

Before route declaration, instead of,

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

And Express will take care of your request. :)

Full example will looks like,

```
const express       = require('express')
const app           = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

app.post('/test-url', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    return res.send("went well")
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("running on port 3000")
})
```

Answer (score 15):

In order to get access to the post data we have to use `body-parser`. Basically what the `body-parser` is which allows express to read the body and then parse that into a `Json` object that we can understand.

Answer (score 14):

**Understanding Requests Body**

> When receiving a POST or PUT request, the request body might be
>   important to your application. Getting at the body data is a little
>   more involved than accessing request headers. The request object
>   that's passed in to a handler implements the ReadableStream interface.
>   This stream can be listened to or piped elsewhere just like any other
>   stream. We can grab the data right out of the stream by listening to
>   the stream's 'data' and 'end' events.
>
> The chunk emitted in each 'data' event is a Buffer. If you know it's
>   going to be string data, the best thing to do is collect the data in
>   an array, then at the 'end', concatenate and stringify it.
>
> ```
> let body = [];
> request.on('data', (chunk) => {
>   body.push(chunk);
> }).on('end', () => {
>   body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
>   // at this point, `body` has the entire request body stored in it as a string
> });
> ```

**Understanding body-parser**

As per its documentation

> Parse incoming request bodies in a middleware before your handlers,
>   available under the req.body property.

As you saw in the first example, we had to parse the incoming request stream manually to extract the body. This becomes a tad tedious when there are multiple form data of different types. So we use the body-parser package which does all this task under the hood.

It provides four modules to parse different types of data

- [JSON body parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions)
- [Raw body parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserrawoptions)
- [Text body parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparsertextoptions)
- [URL-encoded form body parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions)

After having the raw content body-parser will use one of the above strategies(depending on middleware you decided to use) to parse the data. You can read more about them by reading their documentation.

After setting the `req.body` to the parsed body, body-parser will invoke `next()` to call the next middleware down the stack, which can then access the  request data without having to think about how to unzip and parse it.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to use a separate npm package `body-parser`, the latest express (4.16+) has the body-parser middleware built-in that can be used like this:

```js
const app = express();
app.use(express.json({ limit: '100mb' }));
```

p.s. Not all functionalities of `body-parser` are present in the new `express.json()` middleware. Refer to the documentation for full usage [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html)

Comment: Note: Internally the Expess 4.16+ still uses library 'body-parser'.

Answer (score 11):

It parses the HTTP request body. This is usually necessary when you need to know more than just the URL you hit, particular in the context of a POST or PUT PATCH HTTP request where the information you want is contains in the body.

Basically its a middleware for parsing JSON, plain text, or just returning a raw Buffer object for you to deal with as you require.

Answer (score 9):

These are all a matter of convenience.

Basically, if the question were 'Do we *need* to use `body-parser`?' The answer is 'No'. We can come up with the same information from the client-post-request using a more circuitous route that will generally be less flexible and will increase the amount of code we have to write to get the same information.

This is kind of the same as asking 'Do we *need* to use `express` to begin with?' Again, the answer there is no, and again, really it all comes down to saving us the hassle of writing more code to do the basic things that express comes with 'built-in'.

On the surface - `body-parser` makes it easier to get at the information contained in client requests in a variety of formats instead of making you capture the raw data streams and figuring out what format the information is in, much less manually parsing that information into useable data.

Answer (score 7):

Keep it simple :

- if you used `post` request so you will need the `body` of the request, so you
  will need `body-parser`.
- No need to install *body-parser* with `express`, but you have to `use` it if you will
  receive post request.

`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`

```
{ extended: false }
```

*false* meaning, you do not have nested data inside your *body* object. Note that: the request data embedded within the request as a body Object.