# How parse JSON properties from request body in express server?

Tags: json, node.js, express, post

I've set up a node server that passes requests to a utility class.
So far the `POST` request is hit but the mapping to the body property values are undefined. [Bodyparser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306569/what-does-body-parser-do-with-express-in-nodejs) is also used in the post method to assist in the Json parse.

I stepped into the request and see that the body is populated and see that the property names are correct as shown in the paste below:

`body: { '{\n\t"Email":"brian@gmail.com",\n\t"Dashboard_Name":"my dash 4",\n\t''},`

But the below mapping to the values assinged via `req.body.propertyname` return undefined:

```
var p_email = req.body.Email;
var p_dashboardName = req.body.Dashboard_Name;
```

**Question:**

How can you parse JSON properties from request body in express server?

**JSON object posted:**

This is the JSON that I post to the server using Postman:

```
{
    "Email":"brian@gmail.com",
    "Dashboard_Name":"my dash 4"

}
```

**Gist** of the express server and associated utility method SaveUserProfile:

Express server -

```
var express     = require('express');
var UserLDAP  = require('./utilities/UserLDAP'); //utility file containing the POST method
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


const url        = require('url');
const app        = express();
var sql          = require('mssql');
const cors       = require('cors');
const path       = require('path');


sql.connect("********************************************************************")
.then((connection1) => {

    sql.globalConnection = connection1;

    app.use(cors());

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 


    app.post('/OOO/SaveUserProfile', UserLDAP.SaveUserProfile) 


    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000 );
    logger.info(`listening to port ${process.env.PORT}`);
}).catch((err) => {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
    logger.error(err.message);
});
```

UserLDAP.js -

```
var sql = require('mssql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');




//Save User Profile

        exports.SaveUserProfile = function(req, res) {


        req.app.use(bodyParser.json());
        req.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

        var request = new sql.Request(sql.globalConnection);

        console.log(req);

        var p_email = req.body.Email;
        var p_dashboardName = req.body.Dashboard_Name;


    };
```

Comment: which version of express are you using?

Comment: 4.1 express last time we updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had incorrect content-type set in Postman on the object being posted. Needed to be set as:

```
application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score -1):

Currently you have no way of knowing if a parser like body-parser.json has produced an error which seems the obvious place to start given the content is there but the result isn't.

I had a look at body-parser and found an [issue](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/issues/122) that spoke to the problem of detecting a json error which I would expect to be good to know.

The developer suggested the following as one method.

```
app.use(errorFork(bodyParser.json(),   
function (err, req, res, next) { 
    // do stuff with only body parser errors 
})) 

// this is an example; you can use any pattern you like. 
function errorFork(middleware, errorHandler) { 
    middleware(req, res, function (err) { 
        if (err) {
            return errorHandler(err, req, res, next) 
        }else{
            return next() 
        }
    }) 
}
```

It isn't a fix but it would give you more info. Something is going wrong with the parsing by what you have indicated the questin is what? The other thing I noticed about your pasted body content is that it isn't valid json (ignoring \n\t) you have a few rouge `'` in there, worth checking. Try copying what is in body (raw) and put it through a json validator site like [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) just as a double check and see if body-parser is returning any errors.