# Request body undefined in node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to get the username and password from a form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">  
  Username:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Username" value="Username">
  <br>
  Password:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Password" value="Password">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is then received by this:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
console.log(req.body.username);
console.log(req.body.password);
});
```

However no matter what enctype I put in, the username and password is always undefined. What is the error?

P.S Was using body-parser

Comment: I still get undefined for username and password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does body-parser do with express in nodejs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306569/what-does-body-parser-do-with-express-in-nodejs) - I'm guessing you haven't installed body-parser and called `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())` in your app.

Comment: Also, you might want to use placeholder instead of value on your inputs, and maybe mark them 'required'.  `<input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" required>`

Comment: I have installed body parser and i've included 
    

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

Comment: Call `console.log(req.body)` and search needed fields inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
console.log(req.body.Username);
console.log(req.body.Password);
```

Comment: Thats it. Thank you.