# JSON data is not received on POST request?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, serve

I am Trying to insert data into Database using post request as follows

```
127.0.0.1:3000/api/users?fname=asd&lname=edc&emailid=asdas.asds@gmail.com&userpass=dasd
```

but in database blank data is entered. I am using MongoDB for database.

I am doing this using AJAX request following is the code I am Using

```
addUser(dataUser){
 console.log("Adding user:", dataUser);
 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST', url: '/api/users', contentType: 'application/json',
   data: JSON.stringify(dataUser),
   success: function(data) {
     console.log("check it");
   }.bind(this),
   error: function(xhr, status, err) {
     // ideally, show error to user.
     console.log("Error adding bug:", err);
   }
 });
}
```

this is mt POST method in nodeJS file

```
app.post('/api/users', function(req,res){
 console.log("Req body:", req.body);
 var newUser = req.body;
 db.collection("Users").insertOne(newUser, function(err, result) {
   var newId = result.insertedId;
   db.collection("Users").find({_id: newId}).next(function(err, doc) {
     res.json(doc);
   });
 });
});
```

I checked that dataUser variable giving correct values after converting into JSON but still at nodeJS code I am getting Blank JSON Data

Comment: What are you getting in `req.body`?

Comment: user credentials

Answer (score 0):

For getting body from req with express you will need `body-parser` module using `npm install body-parser` as `body-parser` module has been removed from recent release of `express`.

After adding this dependancy you need to add these lines in you nodejs file.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Refer

- [What does body-parser do with express in nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306569/what-does-body-parser-do-with-express-in-nodejs)
- [How do you extract POST data in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js)

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: Appreciate if you can give thumbs up and mark this as useful. @AviatorX

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/api/users', function(req,res){
 console.log("Req body:", req.body);

 //parse json string
 var newUser = JSON.parse(req.body);

 db.collection("Users").insertOne(newUser, function(err, result) {
   var newId = result.insertedId;
   db.collection("Users").find({_id: newId}).next(function(err, doc) {
     res.json(doc);
   });
 });
});
```