# Read data and assign to variable

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to read a from Mongo DB and assign a value to a variable . Does not work.

```
var collection = db.get('accesstoken');
  collection.find({},{},function(e,docs){
    console.log(docs);
    var global_token_var = docs.toArray()[0].access_token;
    console.log(" global token variable set to " + global_token_var);
  });
```

Output as below

> [ { _id: 594aaa17f0db330e70bd6e89,
>       access_token: '76c9b8a60b4f4402bdc7082b945d77899f1282d2',
>       Expires_in: 86400000 } ]
>   undefined
>   (node:1104) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejec
>   tion id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'toArray' of undefined*

So console.log(doc) is returing the JSON object correctly. but variable remains undefined .
I need the access_token in a variable . Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: It's already an array. You are using "mongojs" or similar, which already returned the result of `.find()` as an array. `.toArray()` is a method of the "raw" node driver.

Comment: So simply `docs[0].access_token`

Comment: It worked after removing the .toArray(). Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

sorry i cant comment, but i think you need to require body parser, they have a json parser for incoming requests:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json 
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

also question might be related to this:
[What does body-parser do with express in nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306569/what-does-body-parser-do-with-express-in-nodejs)

thats if your using express, if not then i would imagine you would have to parse in some way. i use express so i would recommended the package. hope im reading this correctly, best of luck

Comment: Um. No. The question has a simple error where the OP has misinterpreted the documentation. This answer has nothing to do with the question and the question is actually resolved if you actually read the comments.