# Why the req object needs to parsed in Express?

Tags: node.js, express

Below is the code I am using:

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

// MIDDLEWARE
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Hello from the Middleware 1');
  console.log(req.body);

  next();
});

app.use(express.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Hello from the Middleware 2');
  console.log(req.body);

  next();
});
```

The first Middleware logs the req.body as **undefined**, but the 2nd Middleware logs the req.body as it is. I am new to Node.Js and I could not find the right explanation for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer address the "why it does not work", but not the original question, a.k.a "Why does req.body **needs** to be parsed".

The short answer is that you don't really know in advance if the body will be, effectively, a JSON object. The `.json()` basically ensures that you have a JSON as a body.

You can read a more thorough and better explanation on this [S/O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45288077/5467710).

Please note that `express` switched from using a third-party library known as `body-parser`, to using their own `.json()` method.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for explaining. Further, I tested the middleware by sending a request with just a text body, and the third middleware printed an empty object. So, if the request body type is not JSON then express.json() will just return an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

You have *three* middlewares:

- in the first, `req.body` is still undefined
- the second is `express.json()`, this parses the request body and fills `req.body` accordingly
- the third then logs `req.body`.