# Accessing raw POST data in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to write a stupidly simple Hello World program in Express that outputs some basic data about the current HTTP request.

For POST requests, I'd like to see the raw POST body.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

function handleRequest(req, res) {
    console.log('\n-- INCOMING REQUEST AT ' + new Date().toISOString());
    console.log(req.method + ' ' + req.url);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('Hello World!');
}

app.all('/*', (req, res) => handleRequest(req, res));
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

When I fire off any type of POST request from Postman, `req.body` is set to `undefined`. Why is `req.body` empty? How can I print out the raw POST data? I don't need a parsed version of the POST body, just the raw data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does body-parser do with express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306569/what-does-body-parser-do-with-express) - TL;DR, you need the `body-parser` middleware installed to be able to handle request bodies.

Comment: use body-parser https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to read the body of a post request you need [body-parser.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)
If you also need to parse multipart/form-data you need [multer.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

after you npm install them:

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const upload = multer();
const app = express();

// create application/json parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

function handleRequest(req, res) {
    console.log('\n-- INCOMING REQUEST AT ' + new Date().toISOString());
    console.log(req.method + ' ' + req.url);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send('Hello World!');
}

app.post('/*', upload.any(), (req, res) => handleRequest(req, res));
app.all('/*', (req, res) => handleRequest(req, res));
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'));
```

Comment: This still seems to produce empty objects in some cases. It doesn't work when I use the 'form-data' option in Postman.

Comment: Can you try with extended: true? If you want to post multipart/form-data you need multer - https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: Still not the raw POST data, but this will also cover my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1. If you required parsing of url-encoded (non-multipart) form data, as well as JSON, try adding:

   ```
   var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


   // Put these statements before you define any routes.
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
   app.use(bodyParser.json());
   ```
2. To handle multi-part form data, the bodyParser.urlencoded() body parser will not work. you can refer [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#readme) for alternatives of extracting data from form-data

Comment: Would you mind having a look at this one please? Am I doing something wrong?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76064309/unexpected-end-of-form-at-callfinal-error