# Multipart form data post method using express js

Tags: javascript, express, pug, multipartform-data

I tried to post form data to my express js server side. This is my `pug` file

```
form(action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data")
 input(type="file" accept="image/*" name="profileimage")
 input(type="text" name="username")
 input(type="submit" value="Upload")
```

After that I tried to log the post data with `req.body` inside server side js as follow. That is my `profile.js`

```
router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log('Body- ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
});
```

And this is my console result
`body- {}`

If I post without `enctype="multipart/form-data"` like `form(action="/profile" method="post")`, I can get the post data from my console result.

Comment: duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49029893/accessing-raw-post-data-in-express/49030208#49030208

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing raw POST data in Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49029893/accessing-raw-post-data-in-express)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use a middleware to handle multipart form data, i think the most famous one is **multer**.

You can find it here: https://github.com/expressjs/multer

To use it:

1. First add it to your modules with `npm install --save multer` in your root project
2. Then import it in your .js file `var multer  = require('multer');`
3. Choose your upload directory by setting the `dest` argument in the `multer` constructor: `var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });`
4. Now just pass it as a middleware in your POST function as follows:

   ```
   router.post('/', upload, function (req, res) {
     console.log('Body- ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
   });
   ```

And don't forget to read the documentation at their github repo.

Comment: Thanks @Atef but this would slit the data into req.file and req.body.
Please is there a way to have in all in one formData. in req.body so that I can send the data as it is to another api.

Comment: @Vixson I had the same situation and I would suggest using `formidable`, as it has a simpler handler and doesn't split into req.file and req.body. It's also 4 times the size of `multer` but still light IMO

Answer (score 3):

`express-formidable` module is best suited to send post data to the server I think.
install express-formidable with following command `npm install express-formidable`
below is a sample code example

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let formidable = require('express-formidable');
let path = require('path');

app.use(formidable({
  encoding: 'utf-8',
  uploadDir: path.join(__dirname, 'uploads'),
  multiples: true,
  keepExtensions: true// req.files to be arrays of files
}));

app.post('/uploads',function(req,res){
  console.log('Files '+JSON.stringify(req.files));// contains data about file fields
  console.log('Fields '+JSON.stringify(req.fields));//contains data about non-file fields
});
```

you have create a folder **uploads** in your project root directory. All the data related to file will be in `req.files` and non-file data will be in `req.fields` I have used it with `ejs` templating engine and it would work just as fine with `pug`. click **[This Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-formidable)** for further information about `express-formidable`