# Node.Js wont Upload file to Directory

Tags: node.js, rest, postman

I want to simulate an upload in Node.js REST api.
I want to make the REST api upload the files to a directory and then save the URL of the saved file to the database table.
For some reason, I dont know of , he just tells me , "No Files uploaded" But looking thru, everything seems okay.

I am testing thru Postman, so thats where i seem to be getting the output and what it tells me.

My code is looking like this:

```
app.post('/api/createpost', function (req,res){
    if(!req.files) return res.status(400).send('No Files uploaded');
    
    const {foo} = req.files;
    const uploadTo = `postimages/${foo.name}`;
    
    foo.mv(uploadTo, (err) =>{
    if(err) return res.status(500).send(err);
        
    //push data to mysql Db
    
    var username = req.body.username;
    var imgUrl = 'http://localhost/'+uploadTo;
    var post = req.body.post;
    
    dbConn.query('INSERT INTO instagramclonedbposts SET ?', [username, imgUrl, post], function(error, results, fields){
        if(error) throw error;
        return res.send({error:false, message: 'Post Created'});
        });
    
    });
});
```

Testing in Postman, I have this :

[image: node-Postman.png]

Could there be something i am missing?

Comment: You need to use some middleware like **multer** https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49067423/multipart-form-data-post-method-using-express-js