# Express Body Parser with both JSON and binary data passing capability

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, body-parser

In my express app router, I've routes for accepting POST request of JSON data as well as binary data. The problem is when I use body parser for passing JSON data, it also considers the binary data as JSON and gives error while POSTing binary data. i.e. when I use:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
```

And When I remove this, It only works for binary data. Following is my route for POSTing binary file.

```
router.post('/file', function (req, res) {
    var gridfs = app.get('gridfs');
    var writeStream = gridfs.createWriteStream({
        filename: 'file_name_here'
    });
    writeStream.on('close', function (file) {
        res.send(`File has been uploaded ${file._id}`);
    });
    req.pipe(writeStream);
});
```

I've also tried moving this file route to other router. In that case, when I don't set anything regarding body parser, it still gives the same error.

**One fix that works correctly is placing this file route in my main `app.js` prior to setting body parser.** But I think this would not be good approach. I want these routes to be in separate files.

So what I'm missing here? Any alternatives will also be appreciated.

**EDIT**

As per the answer, I've first separated out my routers which requires body parsing and which do not. Also removed the bodu parser from my main `app.use()` Now in the router in which, I need body parser, I've added those 2 lines. But the behavior is same.

When I add those 2 lines, only JSON reqquest works and when I remove, only binary POST req. works.

Here is my updated code:

`app.js`

```
    const express = require('express');
const app = module.exports = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const port = 8080;


// //parsing incoming requests using body-parser middlewares
// app.use(bodyParser.json());
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));


//adding routes
app.use(require('./routes/additionRouter'));
app.use(require('./routes/mediaRouter'));

//catch 404 file not found here
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const err = new Error('Page Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

//Error Handler
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.send(err.message);
});

app.listen(port, () => {console.log('Server listening on port: ' + port)});
```

`additionRouter.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

var exported = require('../config/dbConnection');

 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 // parsing incoming requests using body-parser middlewares
 router.use(bodyParser.json());
 router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

//Endpoint for adding new challenge
router.post('/endpoint1', (req, res, next) => {

});

module.exports = router;
```

and `mediaRouter.js`

```
    const express = require('express');
const mediaRouter = express.Router();
const exported = require('../config/dbConnection');

exported.cb((gridfs) => {
    //For adding media files to database named 'mediadb'
    //POST http://localhost:8080/file
    mediaRouter.post('/file', function (req, res) {
        // var gridfs = app.get('gridfs');
        var writeStream = gridfs.createWriteStream({
            filename: 'file_name_here'
        });
        writeStream.on('close', function (file) {
            res.send(`File has been uploaded ${file._id}`);
        });
        req.pipe(writeStream);
    });

    //GET http://localhost:8080/file/[mongo_id_of_file_here]
    mediaRouter.get('/file/:fileId', function (req, res) {
        // var gridfs = app.get('gridfs');
        gridfs.createReadStream({
            _id: req.params.fileId // or provide filename: 'file_name_here'
        }).pipe(res);
    });

});


module.exports = mediaRouter;
```

Comment: You may need to use multer in the specific route you want, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49029893/accessing-raw-post-data-in-express/49030208#49030208

Comment: But I think multer  is for getting binary data in `res.body`. But I'm not saving this binary data to database from `res.body`, as you can see in above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By specifying

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));
```

your entire app uses the body parser middleware. You could create another middleware to handle whether or not the body parser is used. For example:

```
const bodyParse = bodyParser.json();
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if(req.originalUrl == "restOfUrl/file") next();
    else bodyParse(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But Please see the updated question.

Comment: Can you try the second proposal I made in my answer. It seems better to me. Also out of curiosity what happens if you define app.use(require('./routes/mediaRouter'));
before app.use(require('./routes/additionRouter'));

Comment: when you send the binary what type is the request?

Comment: Wait, I think I've provided URL wrong. Let me check again,

Comment: Thanks, It's now working perfectly. Please remove the 1st part of answer, for others who might come here.

Comment: You are Welcome