# set specific bodyParser for just one route express

Tags: node.js, express

I set `app.use(bodyParser.json());` in my app.js (main file).
I need to change with `bodyParser.text()` in another file (foo.js) just for one route. External service send me a request POST `'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'` and I need to retrieve the content

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express Body Parser with both JSON and binary data passing capability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49067596/express-body-parser-with-both-json-and-binary-data-passing-capability)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the following API Doc at https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.METHOD

You can add middleware(s) to a specific route:

```
app.get('/', bodyParser.text(), function (req, res) {
  ...
})
```

Comment: nice! I Must to have a different router? I can do IF inside a same route?
Because my route is called from external service

Comment: Sorry but I'm not following. Can you add an example to the question?

Comment: external service calls my route /foo. Sometimes use 'application/json' and sometime 'text/plain'. I'd like to use always /foo route.

Comment: Yes. See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#change-accepted-type-for-parsers. You can use both middlewares with `use` and enforce parser according to the content-type header

Answer (score 7):

If you're coming here circa 2021 or later, here is how I set up my `app.js` file for this issue.

```
// Import your various routers
const stripeEventsRouter = require('./routes/stripeEvents')
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users')
const commentsRouter = require('./routes/comments')

// use raw parser for stripe events
app.use('/stripeEvents', express.raw({ type: '*/*' }), stripeEventsRouter)

// use express.json parser for all other routes
app.use(express.json())

// set up the rest of the routes
app.use('/users', usersRouter)
app.use('/comments', commentsRouter)
// ...anything else you add below will use json parser
```

Answer (score 1):

For express 4XX, you do not need to install body-parser anymore:

```
router.use('/endpoint', express.text(), itemRoute);
```

You can read more here: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.text