# Nodejs: Cannot Read property 'city' of undefined

Tags: node.js, rest, ejs

i am using Express & Ejs & body-parser ; Server js:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {

       if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)
 console.log(req.body)

});
```

My Index.Ejs File

```
<div class="container">
                <fieldset>
                  <form action="/" method="post">
                    <input name="city" type="text" class="ghost-input" placeholder="Enter a City" required>
                    <input type="submit" class="ghost-button" value="Get Weather">
                  </form>                       
               </fieldset>
              </div>
```

i get this Error in console:-

```
Cannot set headers after they are sent to client
```

Comment: I haven't worked with EJS but I think you should use the `body-parser` middleware for Express.

Comment: Let me know if you've figured that out

Comment: You were right here it is :-

Comment: You were right here it is 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306569/what-does-body-parser-do-with-express

Comment: I posted the answer so that other people can see better. Let me know if you have trouble with setting it up.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in th comments, you should use the [`body-parser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware for Express.

Comment: i used this code after installing body-parser:
 if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)
     console.log(req.body.city);

Now on html page i get :bad request

Comment: Please edit your question and add the relevant code so we can have a better understanding.

Comment: Ok i will do it instantly