# Angular 5 Post data with Nodejs - Wrong format of body

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular5

I am using nodejs as back-end for angular 5 application . When I am posting data with http post request then it coming at nodejs in wrong formate (Values as property)- 
This is my service code of angular 5 -

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let body = { EmailAddress: email, Password: password };

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/user/login', body, options )
        .map((response: Response) => {
            let user = response.json();
            if (user && user.token) {
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            }
        });
}
```

This is Node API - in body I am getting value as property

```
app.post('/api/user/login', urlencodedBodyparser, function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    User.find({ "EmailAddress": req.body["EmailAddress"], "Password": req.body["Password"] }, function (err, users) {
        console.log(users.length);
        if (err != null) {
            sendError(err, res);
        }
        if (users != null) {
            var count = users.length;
            if (count > 0) {
                response.data = users[0];
                res.json(response);
            }
            else {
                sendError({ message :'No user found'}, res);
                console.log("Login Failed");
            }
        }
        else {
            sendError(err, res);
        }
    })
});
```

Code for body parser -

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var urlencodedBodyparser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

app.use(urlencodedBodyparser);

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try to change the header content-type to json

> application/json

like this:

```
    options() {
        const headers = new Headers({
            'content-type': 'application/json'
        });
        const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return options;
    }




   login(): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/user/login', this.options()).
            map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }
```

Comment: @amethianil please vote up the response if you have used it to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use body-parser middleware https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser
Here is more information [What does body-parser do with express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306569/what-does-body-parser-do-with-express)
Try to use this :

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

Comment: I am using body parser -Please check I have added it in question. Let me know what I am doing wrong

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Did you try what @MedMANS say? change header to json ?

Comment: I used both json and urlencoded Parser but not working . When I am using urlencoded parser then its working fine from post man but not working when calling same api from angular 5 code with urlencoded content type . So think i am missing something in angular . Please help out