# validate the whole request object with joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, joi

I created a middleware that validates the request input before calling the controller logic.

Let's say I have a "get user by id" - route

```
const usersController = require('../controllers/users.js');
const usersControllerPolicy = require('../policies/users.js');

router.get('/:userId', usersControllerPolicy.getUserById, usersController.getUserById);

// other routes
```

Before executing the controller I use the policy to validate the params and the body. My policy module for users is

```
const joi = require('joi');
const schemaValidation = require('../middleware/schemaValidation.js');

module.exports = {
    getUserById: (req, res, next) => {
        schemaValidation({
            userId: joi.string().guid().required()
        }, req, res, next);
    }

    // other routes
}
```

The `userId` is a route parameter, not a variable within the body. The 
`schemaValidation` middleware validates the given schema and calls `next()` or sends a `400` response.

```
const joi = require('joi');
const requestResponder = require('../helpers/requestResponder.js');

module.exports = (schema, req, res, next) => {
    const { error } = joi.validate(req, schema);

    if (error)
        return requestResponder.sendBadRequestError(res);

    next();
}
```

When I call this route with `/users/137eaa6f-75c2-46f0-ba7c-c196fbfa367f` I get this error

> message: '"userId" is required'

but the validation should be fine. I checked the validation `joi.validate(req, schema)` by logging `req.params` and the userId is available. What am I missing?

---

**Edit:**

I know I could validate `req.params` but what if I want to update a user? I would have to validate the params (userId) and the body (name, age, ...)

Comment: If `userID` is available in `req.params` then should you validate `req.params`? e.g. `joi.validate(req.params, schema)`

Comment: @Igor yes but I need to validate the params and the body. I pass in the userId as a parameter but there might be variables to validate in the body too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your joi validation schema should reflect `req` object structure, that should work:

```
const joi = require('joi');
const schemaValidation = require('../middleware/schemaValidation.js');

module.exports = {
    getUserById: (req, res, next) => {
        schemaValidation(joi.object({
            params: joi.object({
                userId: joi.string().guid().required()
            }).unknown(true)
        }).unknown(true), req, res, next);
    }

    // other routes
}
```

When you need to validate both body and params:

```
const joi = require('joi');
const schemaValidation = require('../middleware/schemaValidation.js');

const paramsValidation = joi.object({
    userId: joi.string().guid().required()
}).unknown(true);

const bodyValidation = joi.object({
    name: joi.string().required()
}).unknown(true);

module.exports = {
    getUserById: (req, res, next) => {
        schemaValidation(joi.object({
            params: paramsValidation,
            body: bodyValidation
        }).unknown(true), req, res, next);
    }

    // other routes
}
```

But i would rather prefer to validate them separately with 3 joi schemas (body, params, query) e.g. how it done here https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-joi-validation#validation-ordering

Comment: I'm sorry your first approach did not work. Would you mind providing a snippet for multiple schemas? I don't use express-joi-validation and didn't get how it would be done without

Comment: I updated second example in my answer, that should work

Comment: Did you include body-parser into your express app?
`const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());` > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51231946/cant-access-body-data-from-fetch-put-to-express-server

Comment: I updated my answer, probably you have to add `.unknown(true)` over your joi objects.  if it is not working please provide error output here: `const { error } = joi.validate(req, schema);`