# Apollo Server 2 + Express: req.body missing on post handler

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

Had this working in version 1, but the whole server config has changed.  This is what I have, after adding bodyparser() to the express app as was suggested by Daniel in the comments:

```
    const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    playground: {
        settings: {
            'editor.theme': 'light',
        }
    },
})

// Initialize the app
const app = express();
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.json())

server.applyMiddleware({
    app
})

app.post('/calc', function(req, res){
    const {body} = req;

    console.log("HOWDYHOWDYHOWDY", body) // <== body is {}

    res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json')

    calculate(body)
        .then(result => res.send(result))
        .catch(e => res.status(400).send({error: e.toString()}))    
})
```

The request body is never making it to the app.post handler, though the handler is called. I see it going out from the browser, though.  Any ideas?

**Update:**  Daniel had the correct answer, but I had another problem in the request headers I was using.  Once I fixed that, then the post handler received the body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apollo's middleware applies the bodyparser middleware specifically to the GraphQL endpoint -- it won't affect any other routes your server exposes. In order to correctly populate `req.body`, you need to add the bodyparser middleware yourself, for example:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.post('/calc', routeHandler)

// or...
app.post('/calc', bodyParser.json(), routeHandler)
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, Daniel.  I did what you suggested, and will update my original post.  Now I get an empty JSON object, instead of undefined.  Better? 

So I am a little surprised that the req.body would be empty without bodyparser middleware attached to the app--I would expect a text body.  Without bodyparser.json() = undefined; with = {}

Comment: req.body is undefined by default (see express docs: https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body) You may need to select the appropriate parser to see the body populated correctly, depending on what you're sending. See this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47486182/6024220) and the body-parser docs for more details. Also be aware that if you're using a multipart bodies, you'll need a different library like multer instead.

Comment: Okay, learned something.  I am calling the correct bodyparser, so that's not the problem.  Other people are having similar issues it seems.  Can't find a direct corollary with what I'm trying to do here, but when I find an answer I will post it.

Comment: You could also just try moving your `/calc` route above your `applyMiddleware` call, so it's called and terminated before apollo does anything to your request.

Comment: yes, I did try that, to no effect.  BUT... turns out I had an fault with the request headers in my client code (a line I forgot to delete), so that was the second issue.  Now, no matter where the post handler is placed, I see a body (finally!).  

Marking your response as the answer.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this as well. Fixed it by passing the following into the headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```