# Incorrect interger value on post method

Tags: jquery, node.js

[image]

Above I have a screen shot that states an incorrect integer value on the post method. Also I can share you guys my code below

For front end and back end

```
$(function(){
      function getOneMovie(id) {
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://localhost:3000/movielist' + id,
                  method: 'GET',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  success: function (data) {
                      $($("#updateForm")[0].movieId).val(data._id);
                      $($("#updateForm")[0].intNum).val(data.intNum);
                      $($("#updateForm")[0].name).val(data.name);
                      $($("#updateForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(data.thumnail_path);
                      $($("#updateForm")[0].description).val(data.description);
                      $($("#updateForm")[0].year_released).val(data.year_released);
                      $($("#updateForm")[0].language_released).val(data.language_released);
                      $("#updateForm").show();
                  }
              });
          }

          $("#movieAdded").click(function (a) {
            console.log("movieAdded Click")
              let mydata = {
                  idmovielist: $($("#newForm")[0].intNum).val(),
                  name: $($("#newForm")[0].name).val(),
                  thumnail_path: $($("#newForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(),
                  description: $($("#newForm")[0].description).val(),
                  year_released: $($("#newForm")[0].year_released).val(),
                  language_released: $($("#newForm")[0].language_released).val(),
              }
              displayMovie(mydata);
              console.log("Hidden")
              $("#newForm").trigger("reset");
              $("#newForm").toggle();
              console.log("Hidden")
              a.preventDefault();
          });
          function displayMovie(postdata) {
            console.log("displayMovie 1 : ",postdata);
            var myJSON = JSON.stringify(postdata);
              $.ajax({
                  method: "POST",
                  url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/addMovie",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: myJSON,
                  success: function (data) {
                      console.log("displayMovie 2 : ",data);
                  }
              });
          }

          function loadButton() {
              $(".editMovie").click(function (a) {
                  getOneMovie($($(this)[0]).data("movieId"));
                  a.preventDefault();
              });

              $(".deleteMovie").click(function (a) {
                  deleteMovie($($(this)[0]).data("movieId"));
                  a.preventDefault();
              });
          }
             loadButton();
          function putMovie(id, data) {
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://localhost:3000/movielist/update/' + id,
                  method: 'PUT',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: data,
                  success: function (data) {
                      console.log(data);
                      getOneMovie();
                  }
              });
          }

          $("#updateMovie").on("click", function (a) {
              let data = {
                  idmovielist: $($("#updateForm")[0].intNum).val(),
                  name: $($("#updateForm")[0].name).val(),
                  thumnail_path: $($("#updataForm")[0].thumnail_path).val(),
                  description: $($("#updateForm")[0].description).val(),
                  year_released: $($("#updateForm")[0].year_released).val(),
                  language_released: $($("#updateForm")[0].language_released).val(),
              }

              putMovie($($("#updateForm")[0].movieId).val(), data);
              $("#updateForm").trigger("reset");
              $("#updateForm").toggle();
              a.preventDefault();

          });


      function deleteMovie(id) {
          $.ajax({
              url: "http://localhost:3000/movielist/" + id,
              method: 'DELETE',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function (data) {
                  console.log(data);
              }
          });
      }

});
```

This is my front end

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyparser.json());

const mysqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'Adil@123',
  database: 'movies'

});
mysqlConnection.connect(err=>{
  if (err) {
    console.log('It was not successful \n Error:' + JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));
  } else {
    console.log('Its a success');
  }
  });
 //  Collecting all the movies from the movielist
  app.get('/movielist',(req,res)=> {
    mysqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM movielist", (err, rows,fields)=> {
      if (!err) {
        res.send(rows);
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });
 // Finding a movie based on the `idmovielist` number
   app.get('/movielist',(req,res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query("SELECT * FROM movielist WHERE idmovielist = ?",[req.params.id],(err, rows,fields) =>{
    if (!err) {
      res.send(rows);
    } else {
    console.log(err);
    }
    });
  });

  // Delting a movie
   app.delete('/movielist/:id',(req,res) => {
    mysqlConnection.query("DELETE FROM movielist WHERE idmovielist = ?",[req.params.id],(err,rows,fields) =>{
      if (!err) {
        res.send("Movie is deleted");
      } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
    });
  });
  // Inserting a movie
  app.post('/movielist/addMovie',(req, res) => {
    console.log("movielist/addMovie : ",req.body);
   mysqlConnection.query("INSERT INTO movielist (`idmovielist`,`name`,`thumnail_path`,`description`,`language_released`,`year_released`) VALUES ('"+req.body.idmovielist+"', '"+req.body.name+"','"+req.body.thumnail_path+"', '"+req.body.description+"', '"+req.body.year_released+"', '"+req.body.language_released+"')",
   (err,rows) => {
     if (!err) {
       res.send("Movie is added");
     } else {
       console.log(err);
     }
  });
});

// Updating the movie list
app.put('/movielist/:id',(req,res) =>{
let update = req.body;
mysqlConnection.query("UPDATE movielist SET `year_released` WHERE = '"+update.idmovielist+"'",
(err, results)  => {
    if (!err) {
      res.send("Movie list is updated");
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
});
});


// localhost:3000
app.listen(3000,() => {
  console.log('We got it running');
});
module.exports = app;
```

and this is my back end. I was using the post method couple days ago and it was working could their be something I am doing wrong in my back end and is my SQL statement incorrect

Comment: Can you confirm the result of `$($("#newForm")[0].intNum).val()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyparser.json())
```

Please add this code at line 7.

[What does body-parser do with express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306569)

Comment: thanks it worked but the I had to refresh the page I was trying to do a post method so I do not have to refresh the page for it to show up

Comment: I cannot understand your words, You cannot update server code?