# node.js, express, how to get data from body form-data in post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a simple node.js app. I want to get post body from user.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/api/user', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.body.username);
});

module.exports = app;
```

**server.js**

```
var app = require('./app.js');

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

    var port = server.address().port;

    console.log('Web App Hosted at http://localhost:%s',port);

});
```

When i launch it with `node server.js`, its fine. When i check it with postman,
[image]

in console, it returns

```
Web App Hosted at http://localhost:3000
{}
undefined
```

I have the newest express.

And i have try other thing like add `body-parser`, add header to `content-type`, add `express.urlencoded()`, but none work. i need to get data from `form-data` like postman on picture above. How i can get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does body-parser do with express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306569/what-does-body-parser-do-with-express)

Comment: @zero298 i think is not, because i use the newest express. So i no need body-parser

Answer (score 62, accepted):

after hours, i found it.

body-parser its not required because in newest express is included.

i have found how to get form-data, it require multer(for parsing multipart/form data) middleware. i have found it in [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

first install multer

```
npm install multer --save
```

import multer in your app. for example in my code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();

// for parsing application/json
app.use(express.json()); 

// for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

// for parsing multipart/form-data
app.use(upload.array()); 
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('/api/user', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.body.username);
});

module.exports = app;
```

so, it can receive form-data, raw, or x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: I have also had the same issue and spend 3 hours trying to figure out what went wrong. Finally, I also forgot to include my multer function in my routes :)

Answer (score 4):

you need install  **body-parser**  to parse req.body

```
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

> body-parser extract the entire body portion of an incoming request
>   stream and exposes it on req.body.

Comment: There is a screenshot in the question, where it can be seen that @alfian5229 sends a form-data request, not json. So `express.json()` is useless there.

Comment: @Shubh yeah, and i have the newest express.

Answer (score 4):

Express specifies in their [API docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body) that you have to use one of the provided middlewares to give the body a value. They made this decision because there are many different kinds of formats HTTP request bodies can take, and they don't want to assume which one your app uses.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add `Content-Type: application/json` to Headers? I had the same problem and was solved adding `Content-Type: application/json`.

Comment: yeah, but still undefined

Comment: It didn't solve with express v4.17.1

Answer (score 1):

> I had face same problem.I had solved following way:
>
> 1. First install 'express-fileupload' package.
> 2. include express-fileupload
>
>    `fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')`
> 3. enable files upload
>
>    `app.use(fileUpload({ createParentPath: true }));`
>
> N.B: Or You can use multer package instead of express-fileupload package.as your wish.

Answer (score -1):

```
const express = require("express");
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();
const app = express();
var multiparty = require('multiparty');
var util = require('util');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(upload.array()); 
app.use(express.static('public'));
// default options
const addFileDetail =  (req, res,next) => {
//app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    
  var sampleFile = req.body.filepath;
   console.log(req.body.filepath);
//   var uploads = "./"+req.body.filepath+"/"+req.body.org+"/"+req.body.type+'/';
//       await createDir(uploads);
//   let uploadPath = uploads;

//   if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0) {
//     return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');
//   }

//   // The name of the input field (i.e. "sampleFile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file
//   sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;
//   uploadPath = __dirname + uploadPath + sampleFile.name;

//   // Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server
//   sampleFile.mv(uploadPath, function(err) {
//     if (err)
//       return res.status(500).send(err);
var form = new multiparty.Form();

form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/plain' });
  res.write('received upload:\n\n');
  res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
             console.log('fields: %@', fields);
             console.log('files: %@', files);
});
    // res.send('File uploaded!');
//   });
}

const createDir = (dirPath) => {
    fs.mkdir(dirPath, { recursive: true }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log("Directory is created.");
    });
}

module.exports = {
   // getfile: getfile,
    addFileDetail: addFileDetail,
   // viewFiles: viewFiles
};
 i am getting issue in this.
```

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation of how this resolves the user's question?