# app.use(express.json) doesn't work post request returning an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
const express = require('express');
          app = express();
          PORT = 3030;
    
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      res.send('Hello World')
    });
    
    app.post('/', (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.body);
      res.json(req.body)
    })
    
    app.listen(PORT, err => {
      if(err) {
        return console.log('ERROR', err);
      }
    
      console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}, http://localhost:${PORT}/`)
    });
```

I'm using Postman to test it here is what I'm using.

I'm using form-data:

{number: 123,
new: new}

I've tried using body-parser but it's depreciated.

I'm using express "^4.17.1"

I'm just wondering if it's something local that could be causing the problem because I've looked up a couple of tutorials and they don't have this issue.

[postman details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRprl.png)

I've also tried making a request using fetch:

```
let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      number: '123',
      new: 'new'
    })
  }
  fetch('http://localhost:3030/', options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
```

all I get back is:

`test.html:61 POST http://localhost:3030/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch`

Comment: Similar question here: [How to get data from form body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56758241/node-js-express-how-to-get-data-from-body-form-data-in-post-request)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your postman image shows `form-data` (which is probably `multipart/form-data`) as the content-type which is not something that either of your middleware handlers knows about.

`express.json()` parses JSON content-types like `application/json`.

`express.urlencoded()` parses URl encoded content-types like `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

People often use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) for parsing `multipart/form-data`, but if this data is just simple form data (name/value pairs), then you should encode it as either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `application/json` rather then deploy multer.  Multer is typically used when you have file uploads and that's when `multipart/form-data` is a necessary choice.

Comment: I've also tried using a fetch request but I get:


POST http://localhost:3030/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: @kealanheena - Just change the content-type in Postman to something you have middleware installed for.  Presumably, your `fetch()` usage had some problem because all it does is send an http request, same as Postman.  We can't help you with the `fetch()` issue without a lot more info added to your question about that specific circumstance and error.

Comment: I know it works when I use x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: @kealanheena - Well, it won't work with `multipart/form-data` unless you install Express middleware that knows how to parse that content-type (like multer).  That's what I wrote in my answer.  Is there more to your question than that?

Comment: @kealanheena - If this answered your question, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you a few reputation points for following the proper procedure here.