# req.body undefined on method POST (Express.js)

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I'm doing a MERN test project.

But at the time of testing a post method is not returning the value sent.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: In the future, please just paste the code in instead of making us deal with screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in app.js

```
app.use(express.json());
```

OR

If you want to simple boilerplate and Expressjs project structure then use Express application generator
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Comment: Looks like he had a mistake in the line you're indicating. Instead of using the use() method I had written unsubscribe(). The suggestion fixed the error.

Comment: Sorry  Show this message: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install body-parser

`npm install body-parser --save`

Check this link [What does body-parser do with express?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48364778/10294022)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the comments detect the origin of the problem. A typing error ‍♂️ : when calling `server.unsubscribe(express.json())` instead of using `server.use(express.json())`;

Correcting this line fixed the problem. ✌