# what does app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); do in express js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

##what will happen if i dont add this line to my express code.

`app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does body-parser do with express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306569/what-does-body-parser-do-with-express)

Answer (score 2):

It supports parsing of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` post data

If you don't add this line you won't be able to parse the body of requests with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, this lets you interact with forms sent with the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type much easier within express.

You can simply use the req.body.ELEMENT_NAME with these types of forms. This allows for interaction with more modern browsers that use this content-type when submitting a form. It is extremely beneficial for compatibility and I would recommend using it.