# MongoDB Node Express - data not getting saved while using user.save()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

While this one works perfect with postman get "welcome message" and post /login request, gives no error nor saves data in mongo cloud, but shows could not get response in POSTMAN

index.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Import Routes
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");

dotenv.config();

//Connect To DB
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECT,
{ useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
() => console.log("connected to DB")
);

//Middleware
app.use(express.json());

//Route Middleware
app.use("/api/user", authRoute);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server up and running on port 3000"));
```

User Schema - User.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 6,
        max: 50
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 6,
        max: 25
    }
    ,
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 6,
        max: 1024
    },
    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

auth.js file

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../model/User");

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const user = new User({
    name : req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });
  console.log("Entering Try Catch");
  try {
    console.log(user.name +" - " + user.email);
      const savedUser = await user.save();
      console.log("saved user = " + savedUser);
      res.send(savedUser);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(400).send(err);
  }
});

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Welcome");
});

router.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Console Logged In");
  res.send("Logged In Successful");
});

module.exports = router;
```

It would be of great help, if you could let me know where i'm mistaking. Thanks In Advance !!

Edit : i'm getting all the console till, Entering try catch as well as user.name and user.email

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your help, well it was not mistake in code or any other error for this one particular what i found is pretty strange, on atlas i allowed access to my current IP address despite that it still had this error now after changing it to Allow Access to all it is working, so i guess it should be the issue from mongo side that they should consider few rare incident like this.

Answer (score 0):

> hint: first of all, you should always use **return** for your
> responses.

try this :

```
  try {
    const user = await User.create({
        name : req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    });
    return res.send(user);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).send(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to install `body-parser` middleware for `express` in order to get the values from `req.body`

A good way to debug is `console.log(req.body)` and see if is `undefined`

Detailed answer here: [What does body-parser do with express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306569/what-does-body-parser-do-with-express)

**EDIT:**

Most likely something with your database connection is the problem, because I'm using your code (copy/paste) and everything works fine for me.

You could add
`mongoose.connection.on('error', err => { console.log(err); });` below your `mongoose.connect` inside your `index.js` to debug your mongoose connection, you should wait around 30s-1min after making POST request.

[image: index.js]

And here is my `.env` file : `DB_CONNECT=mongodb://localhost:27017/test`

[image: auth.js]

Comment: ```
//Middleware
app.use(express.json());
```
this does the job

Comment: I edited my answer, does it help to debug? I expect the problem to be at the connection level

Comment: Sular : Thank You very much for the help, but one thing which is out of my mind is that i went to mongo atlas created a cluster and copied the url from there which is present in DB_CONNECT. Now i'm wondering what could have gone wrong. BTW it works fine on local machine

Comment: Hi Paul, could you please point out what could be the issue here as i copied the exact uri from cluster connection, also with the same uri i'm getting a console message as **connected to DB** where as the same thing gives could not get response when sending a GET or POST request

Answer (score 0):

After days of trying I fixed this by just rearranging the order of my middleware

**From this:**

```js
app.use(route);
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

**To this:**

```js
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(route);
app.use(cors());
```