# Sending axios post request returns ERR_BAD_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, express, axios

Im trying to write a simple bowling API on a webserver using expressJS along with a client via the terminal. The terminal sends HTTP request to the webserver to be processed and print out its response. I have 3 relatively simple endpoints to start a game, record a frame, and send current scores. The start endpoint works as intended but when trying run the record endpoint I receive a `ERR_BAD_RESPONSE` error. Here's the endpoint.
Heres the server code with 3 endpoints:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const axios = require('axios');
    
    const app = express();
    
    // Set up a hash map to store the scores for each player
    const scores = {};
    
    // Set up the API routes
    
    // Route to start a new game with up to 8 players
    app.get('/start', (req, res) => {
      // Initialize the scores for each player to 0
      for (let i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        scores[`player${i}`] = 0;
      }
      res.send(`Started a new game with up to 8 players!`);
    });
    
    // Route to record the result of a frame for a player
    app.use(express.json());
    
    app.post('/record', (req, res) => {
      const player = req.body.data.player;
      const score = req.body.data.score;
      scores[player] += score;
      res.send(`Recorded score of ${score} for ${player}`);
    });
    
    // Route to display the current scores for each player
    app.get('/scores', (req, res) => {
      res.send(scores);
    });
    
    // Start the server
    app.listen(3000, () => {
      console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
    });
```

Client code:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

const baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000';

console.log('Welcome to the bowling API!');
async function client(){
  let optionSelect =  await rl.question("Please select an option:\n1)Start a game\n2)Record a frame\n3)Send scores\n", async (option) => {
    if(option === "1"){
      await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/start')
      .then(response => console.log(response.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
      client();
    } else if(option === "2"){
      await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/record', {
        data: {
          player: 'player1',
          score: 10
        }
    })
      .then(response => console.log(response.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
      client();
    } else if(option === "3"){
      await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/scores')
      .then(response => console.log(response.data))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
      client();
    } else{
      console.log('Bad input selected bye bye');
      return;
    }});  
}
client();
```

Heres the output:

```
$ node app.js&
[1] 1050

Chris@DESKTOP-E7JGMQ2 MINGW64 ~/rectangleHealth (main)
$ node otherclient.js
Welcome to the bowling API!
Please select an option:
1)Start a game
2)Record a frame
3)Send scores
1
Started a new game with up to 8 players!
Please select an option:
1)Start a game
2)Record a frame
3)Send scores
2
AxiosError: Request failed with status code 500
    at settle (C:\Users\cmb\rectangleHealth\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.c
js:1859:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\cmb\rectangleHealth\node_module
s\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:2723:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:2
1) {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE',
```

Comment: It looks like you pasted the wrong client code as that appears to be another copy of the server code.

Comment: Probably has to do with a body parser not being setup.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306569/what-does-body-parser-do-with-express

Comment: FYI, your Express code does not show any middleware that would read the POST body and parse it into `req.body` so `req.body` would be empty.  If you're sending JSON from the client, then you would need `app.use(express.json())` before your `/record` route.

Comment: So in addition I to needing middleware I also need bodyparser?

Comment: No, just `app.use(express.json())`

Comment: Updated servercode, like that?