# Why can't we directly access request body. Why do we have to parse the requset body using body-parser or express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
const express = require("express");
const { PORT } = require("./config/config");

const setupAndStartServer = async () => {
    const app = express();

    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body);
        return res.status(200).json({ data: "Hello" });
    });

    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`Server started at ${PORT}`);
    });
};

setupAndStartServer();
```

`console.log(req.body)` outputs `undefined`.

I know that we have to use body-parser and we will be able to read the body.
But I want to know the reason Why we can't directly access it without parsing the request body.

Comment: GET request doesn't have a body.

Comment: "*Why we can't directly access it*" - but you can. `req` is a readable data stream. Just listen to the individual bytes.

Comment: duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/q/38306569/6606524