# Why is my fetch request outputting undefined?

Tags: javascript, express

I'm using a fetch request with the PUT method and giving a body but when I call the endpoint that I defined on my server page, I keep getting undefined.

Does anyone know why?

Here's where the call comes from:

```
<tr>
  <td><%= index %></td>
  <td class="editable" id="item">
    <%= item %>
  </td>
  <td class="editable" id="desc">
    <%= desc %>
  </td>
  <td class="editable" id="status">
    <%= status %>
  </td>
  <td class="editable" id="priority">
    <%= priority %>
  </td>
  <td><button id="delete-button">Delete</button>
    <button onclick="refetch(this)">Edit</button>
  </td>
</tr>

<script>
  async function refetch(btn) {
    if (btn.innerHTML === 'Edit') {
      await fetch('http://localhost:3000/todo', {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: {
          edit: 'true'
        }
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

And my endpoint:

```
app.put("/todo", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

Comment: You should probably have `JSON.stringify({exit: 'true'})` as the body.

Comment: Also `headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" }`

Comment: Added headers and the JSON.stringify, still undefined

Comment: Have you check that your endpoint is properly functioning with Postman or something similar?

Comment: Yeah I get a status 200 when I fetch, just an undefined body

Answer (score 0):

Although the question did not mention, I assumed you're using [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) framework.

The reason for that is most likely that you're not using [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) to allow posting data to your endpoint.

You can find out more about on this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306569/what-does-body-parser-do-with-express#:~:text=No%20need%20to%20install%20body,you%20will%20receive%20post%20request.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306569/what-does-body-parser-do-with-express#:%7E:text=No%20need%20to%20install%20body,you%20will%20receive%20post%20request.).

Try this:
`npm install body-parser`

Then just before your your `app.put(/todo)` add this:

`app.use(require("body-parser").urlencoded({ extended: false }));`

Then try again, I'd recommend you use Postman to test your endpoint accordingly before doing E2E tests.

[Here's a working example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/express-playground-forked-s38n8h?welcome=true)

[On Postman](https://s38n8h-8080.csb.app/test)

I hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: The question has the `express` tag. That should be enough, it doesn't have to say it in the text.

Comment: The problem isn't the body-parser. The problem is that `fetch()` will not automatically convert the object to JSON, you have to call `JSON.stringify()` explicitly in the client.

Comment: @Barmar , I did not notice the express tag. Thank you for that.
However, it's not JSON.stringify, the problem is the lack of body-parser middleware in  express. You can easily test the endpoint I posted above without JSON.stringify and will still work.

Comment: The problem was I needed to add this line of code to my index.js. I overlooked it, app.use("/", express.json());

Comment: @ether I'm glad you've solved it! Cheers!!

Comment: I can't find any mention in the `fetch()` documentation that `body` will be stringified automatically if it's a plain object. Maybe this is browser-specific?

Comment: @Barmar It won't. The OPs code is sending `[object Object]` as the body. They did however mention "*Added headers and the JSON.stringify*" in a comment