# How to send node js server side data to angular js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sessionstorage

I am new to mean stack , in fact working on my very first project , i want to remember the request from the specific browser , which i have done using cookies . After that i want to send the history data from the server specific to every request  which   i am not able to do , as i couldnt find a suitable way . i tried using sessionstorage in angular js but that doesnt pull the session data i kept in node js ) Please let me know how is make it .

Node js: 
when i have set session var titles here in node js

```
var chkck = function(req,res,next){
    console.log("inside cookie callback .. ");

req.session.titles = req.session.titles || [];
//titles.push(req.params.)
 req.session.titles.push("22");
    res.sendFile("F:/customer/public/index.html");
}


app.use(chkck);


app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.sendFile("F:/customer/public/index.html");});
```

angular js:
but in angular , i am not able to retrieve the titles from sessionstorage .

```
var nameapp=angular.module('name-App',["ngRoute",'ngCookies','ngStorage']);
    nameapp.controller('NameCtrl',
        function($scope,$http,$window, $cookieStore,$sessionStorage ){
            $scope.arr=[];
         $scope.finddet=function(){


            console.log("sessionstorage.titles"+ $sessionStorage.titles);
}});
```

this gives undefined

Answer (score 2):

In your `Nodejs` code: convert your response to JSON

```
res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

[Sample answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696240/proper-way-to-return-json-using-node-or-express)

AnguarJs:

In your controller file,

```
$http.get(/your_url).then(function(response){

   // You will get the above response here  in response.data

  })
```