# how to make nodejs return a veritable json object to postman?

Tags: json, node.js, postman

i code in nodejs. i have for example an object

```
var foo = {"a": "b"}
```

But when i do

```
res.send(JSON.stringify(foo))
```

postman respons me by default as an HTML.
`res.send(foo)` , the same thing...
But I want to make postman respond me a valid JSON by default
how to do it ?

Comment: I guess you are using express. You need to configure it to return json format, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696240/proper-way-to-return-json-using-node-or-express)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your code to return a proper json object you need to specify in the head what are you returning;

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
var foo = {"a": "b"}
var json = JSON.stringify(foo);
response.end(json);
```

or if you use `express` just use:

```
res.json(json);
```