# Creating a 'readable' JSON format

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Using Node.js and am fairly new to the software. However this is something that bothered me from my vanilla front-end days. I have a simple html.get stream

```
https.get(url, (res)=>{
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    let body = '';
    res.on('data', (data)=>{
        body += data;
    });

    res.on('end', ()=>{
        body = JSON.parse(body);
        //console.log(typeof body);
        callback(body);
    })
})
```

with the callback function just returning the file to my webpage

```
 function callback(body){
    res.send(body);
}
```

The problem that I have with this is that the file that I send to my server, i.e. var = body , is that the file is... not easily readable. I'm not sure if that makes complete sense so this might be a better explanation:

This is what I want:

```
{
"title": "Google Custom Search - lectures",
"totalResults": "970000000",
"searchTerms": "lectures",
"count": 10,
"startIndex": 11,
"inputEncoding": "utf8",
"outputEncoding": "utf8",
"safe": "off",
"cx": "[REDACTED]"
}
```

with all the whitespaces intact. This is the what the URL for the get gives. However after receiving it and concatenating/parsing it with my algorithm I get:

```
{"title":"Google Custom Search - lectures","totalResults":"970`0000","searchTerms":"lectures","count":10,"startIndex":11,"inputEncoding":"utf8","outputEncoding":"utf8","safe":"off","cx":"[REDACTED]"}]}
```

without any white-spaces or anything. It just comes out as 'blocks of texts'. I (HOPE) I did something wrong and there is a way to preserve the original format when I use the html.get call.

My original plan was to use some 'regex magic' to format it to become more readable, but there should be another way I hope considering the original URL has it formatted it properly. I'm dealing with a big JSON file, so a more readable format would be nice. I'm not sure if I explained my scenario perfectly, this is my first Stack question, but if its not please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810841/how-can-i-pretty-print-json-using-javascript

Comment: That was the thread I was just on. I suppose 'regex magic' is the one true answer for this, huh.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696240/proper-way-to-return-json-using-node-or-express

Comment: JSON.stringify(body, null, 4) or so should do the trick - in my opinion - but it still makes doesn't work properly. Maybe, when I'm concatenating something goes wrong. I'm going to go to sleep, but maybe it will click when I wake up tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple function to format the JSON the way you want. You might find you want a different format for logging vs. web page etc. This wraps the JSON.stringify method (well documented here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify and here:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp.

```
var data = {"title":"Google Custom Search - lectures","totalResults":"970`0000","searchTerms":"lectures","count":10,"startIndex":11,"inputEncoding":"utf8","outputEncoding":"utf8","safe":"off","cx":"[REDACTED]"};

function prettyPrintJSON(data, space = 2) {
    return JSON.stringify(data, null, space);
}
console.log(prettyPrintJSON(data));
```

The output would look like so:

```
{
  "title": "Google Custom Search - lectures",
  "totalResults": "970`0000",
  "searchTerms": "lectures",
  "count": 10,
  "startIndex": 11,
  "inputEncoding": "utf8",
  "outputEncoding": "utf8",
  "safe": "off",
  "cx": "[REDACTED]"
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle example:

https://jsfiddle.net/uovtaxq3/3/

Comment: Thanks! This isn't exactly what I needed, but it helped me figure out my problem. The white space from the get was being written into my parsed JSON as </br> and \n. Just changing res.send() to res.write() managed to fix it.