# Returning json from node back to client

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, response, multer

I have a node.js and express script that is taking a file, running a script on it, and returning stdout to the console log. Instead of logging the stdout to the console, i would like to send the output (which is in JSON) back to the client in a response. I'm seeing that maybe res.send is the proper way to do this. Is this the correct method and where would this go in my code?

```
const multer = require('multer')
const fs = require('fs')
const exec = require('child_process').exec
const express = require('express')

var app = express();

const upload = multer({
    dest: './upload',
    fileFilter: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (file.mimetype != 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') {
            return cb(new Error('Wrong file type'))
        }
        cb(null,true)
    }
}).single('file');

app.post('/upload', upload, function(req, res) {

  const filePath = req.file.path
  exec(`./script.sh ${filePath}`,
      function (error, stdout, stderr) {
          console.log(stdout);
          if (error !== null) {
              console.log('exec error: ' + error);
          }
          res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          res.send(JSON.stringify({ test: 'test' }));
      });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Generaly, one way is:

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.send(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));
```

But since Express.js 3x the response object has a json() method which sets all the headers correctly for you and returns the response in JSON format.

Example:

```
 res.json({"foo": "bar"});
```

As a reference to here: [Proper way to return JSON using node or Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696240/proper-way-to-return-json-using-node-or-express)

In your case, you can try something like this:

```
app.post('/upload', upload, function(req, res) {

const filePath = req.file.path
exec(`./script.sh ${filePath}`,
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      if (error !== null) {
          console.log('exec error: ' + error);
      } 
      res.json(stdout);
  });
});
```

Comment: Refer to what i have done above, as i just made an edit. I have also tried the way you suggested. Both add nothing new to my response. I am viewing via the console in my browser and each response looks the exact same, and doesnt include what i am attempting to add.

Comment: If this is your whole code, it seems like you miss the initialisation of the express server 
something like:

const express = require('express');
const app = express(); 

try this tutorial and advance from there:

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

Comment: didnt miss it. Its up top

Comment: look again, as i see you only required it:

const app = require('express')

but what need to be done:

const express = require('express')
const app = express();
-- but hey maybe i'm wrong and the server is up, and that way i don't understand why the res.json doesn't work for you.

Comment: edited accordingly....wasnt missing from my code, just from the post....the problem still persists

Comment: try this:    
res.status(200).json({"foo": "bar"});
==
maybe surrond it with a try,catch and see if an error thrown.

Comment: does the "console.log(stdout);" works? if so, does "res" even exist in that scope? maybe 'res' is undefined? try to return something as i suggested without the exec function and callback and see, maybe 'res' isn't pass into exec as you expected.

Comment: i guess this is it, try to put it inside a promise and resolve it on success, your promise .then should do the res.status(200).json(stdout) from the scope of app.post.