# Can't Edit and Update properties with form Reactjs and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, forms, input

So I'm using Nodejs, MongoDB and Reactjs
and I'm trying to Edit properties of projects.
I have multiple projects and when I want to edit properties of one I can't do it. We can access to properties inside inputs, we can see Title and Type but can't even delete, write, he access to properties by its ID but then I can't change it, I guess I have multiple problems here than.

I'll write here my server code, and my Edit/Update project page and a gif with an example when I say that I can't even change anything on inputs.

[image]

My server code:

```
//Render Edit Project Page byId 
app.get('/dashboard/project/:id/edit', function(req, res){
 let id = req.params.id;

Project.findById(id).exec((err, project) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    res.json(project);
});
}


//Update Projects Properties byId
app.put('/dashboard/project/:id/edit', function(req, res){
 var id = req.params.id;

 var project = {
   title: req.body.title,
   typeOfProduction: req.body.typeOfProduction
 };

 Project.findByIdAndUpdate(id, project, {new: true}, 
 function(err){
   if(err){
       console.log(err);
   }
   res.json(project);
  })
};
```

My React Component Edit Project Page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

import './EditProject.css';


class EditProject extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //project: {}
        title: '',
        typeOfProduction: ''
    };
}

inputChangedHandler = (event) => {
    const updatedProject = event.target.value;
}

componentDidMount() { 
// console.log("PROPS " + JSON.stringify(this.props));
    const { match: { params } } = this.props;

    fetch(`/dashboard/project/${params.id}/edit`)
    .then(response => {  return response.json()
    }).then(project => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(project));
        this.setState({
            //project: project
            title: project.title,
            typeOfProduction: project.typeOfProduction
        })

    })
}

render() {

    return (
        <div className="EditProject"> EDIT
        <form method="POST" action="/dashboard/project/${params.id}/edit?_method=PUT">
            <div className="form-group container">
                <label className="form--title">Title</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control " value={this.state.title} name="title" ref="title" onChange={(event)=>this.inputChangedHandler(event)}/>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group container">
                <label className="form--title">Type of Production</label>
                <input type="text" className="form-control " value={this.state.typeOfProduction} name="typeOfProduction" ref="typeOfProduction"  onChange={(event)=>this.inputChangedHandler(event)}/>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group container button">
                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default" value="Submit" onClcik={() => onsubmit(form)}>Update</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
    );
    }
}
export default EditProject;
```

> **Erros that I have**:
>
> 1- DeprecationWarning: collection.findAndModify is deprecated. Use findOneAndUpdate, findOneAndReplace or findOneAndDelete instead.
>
> 2- Inputs can't change
>
> 3- When click "Update" button:
>   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your update override the entire object because you forgot the $set operator. This is the operator to change only the atributtes of an object and not the entire object replacing!

Example:

```
Model.update(query, { $set: { name: 'jason bourne' }}, options, callback)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, concerning the deprecation warning, you need to change the method findAndModify (As I do not see it here, I guess you're using it elsewhere, or maybe one of the methods you use is calling it) by one of the suggested methods and change your code accordingly.

---

Then, you need to learn about React and controlled components : https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

You need to set the component's state in your onChange handler, such as :

```
this.setState({
    title: event.target.value // or typeOfProduction, depending on wich element fired the event
});
```

This is called a controlled component in React.

---

Concerning the response body you get when clicking on Update button, this is actually what you asked for :

```
res.json(project);
```

returns the project variable as a JSON file, which is displayed on your screenshot.

See this question for more information about it : [Proper way to return JSON using node or Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696240/proper-way-to-return-json-using-node-or-express)

Answer (score 0):

Try replace "value" in input tag with "placeholder"