# How can I read the json file which is updating after a time interval continuously in React JS project

Tags: reactjs

I have a sample_data.json(this json file is located in my local HDD) file which I can read from my React JS project.

Now the problem is, if I change the data of the sample_data.json file, how can I fetch the updated data in my project?

I already use **setInterval** method to read the json file after with a 5secs interval. But it fails to read the modified json file.

```
this.timer = setInterval(()=> this.beginSampleData(), 5000);
```

Comment: **exact** data fetching method? system/project env.?

Answer (score 0):

If you import the JSON as a file in your React Project, it will not update until you rebuild the project (or have hot-reloader enabled - but not something you want on a production app). If you want to load the file on the fly, you need to create a nodejs server, create an API that reads the file (see more details on how here: [Proper way to return JSON using node or Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696240/proper-way-to-return-json-using-node-or-express)) then from your react app fetch it from this endpoint instead of the file directly.