# Node.js : How to respond with json object after parse from get request with url params

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I am new to the backend and node.js. I am trying to respond to a "GET" post with a JSON object after parsing the existing JSON data with the URL parameters from the post.

Here is the "GET" post

```
search.js
componentDidMount() {
  axios
  .get('http://localhost:3003/?name=Volume')
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({ searches: data });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Error happened during GET!', err);
  });
}
```

This is the external JSON data file

```
data.js
var data = [
{
    "id": "01",
    "name": "Damage Reverse Oil Conditioner",
    "tags": [
        "green",
        "conditioner"
    ]
},
{
    "id": "02",
    "name": "Volume Advance 1",
    "tags": [
        "blue",
        "conditioner"
    ]
},
{
    "id": "03",
    "name": "Volume Advance 2",
    "tags": [
        "red",
        "shampoo"
    ]
}
];
```

Here is the node.js file that is requiring the data.js file

```
app.js

const data      = require('./data');
const http      = require('http');
const url       = require('url');
const hostname  = 'localhost';
const port      = 3003;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
  const queryValue = url.parse(req.url,true).query.name;
  const queryData = (query) => {
    return data.filter((el) =>
      el.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1
    );
  }
  res.end(JSON.stringify(queryData(queryValue)));
}).listen( port );
console.log(`[Server running on ${hostname}:${port}]`);
```

I'm able to parse the url for the params since the const queryValue shows up as "Volume" when consolelog. However, I unable to get the proper JSON response after the filter method that contains only the objects that has matching value of "Volume".

In short I am trying to get a JSON object response that has all the properties of data[0] and data[1].

Any help/ advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to return JSON using node or Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696240/proper-way-to-return-json-using-node-or-express)

Comment: So I don't see anything really wrong with your back-end code. But I see you're using `axios` incorrectly. You'll want something like `axios.get(url).then(response => response.data)` to get the data as `axios` doesn't return the data in its Promise directly so you need to access the `data` property. Read more: https://github.com/axios/axios

Answer (score 1):

At first glance I can see that

```
const queryData = (query) => {
    return data.filter((el) =>
      el.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1
    );
  }
```

this is a function. So, instead of `res.end(JSON.stringify(queryData));` you need to do

```
res.end(JSON.stringify(queryData(queryValue)));
```

Comment: Ok, I changed the code but still not getting the result I need.

Answer (score 0):

On top of @aritra-chakraborty's answer, that `queryData` is a function which you need to pass `queryValue` which can be fixed by doing:

```
res.end(JSON.stringify(queryData(queryValue)))
```

...`axios` returns a Promise containing it's own response object instead of returning data directly. Your response data is accessible inside the `data` property of this response object.

So you need to either fix it like this:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3003/?name=Volume').then(data => {
  this.setState({
    searches: data.data
  });
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Error happened during GET!', err);
});
```

...Or do this

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3003/?name=Volume').then({data} => { 
  this.setState({
    searches: data
  });
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Error happened during GET!', err);
});
```

Read more: https://github.com/axios/axios