# proper way to return json format using node or express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

My question is actually copied from  [Proper way to return JSON using node or Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696240/proper-way-to-return-json-using-node-or-express).
I need the response in this format.

Sample format for response API

```
{
"success":true,
"code":200,
"message":"Ok",
"data": []
}
```

I followed all the methods provided in the above question, but still i couldn't crack the right answer. since i have many apis, i need this response format for every api.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
    );
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,  DELETE, GET");
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});
app.use("/api", employeeRoutes);
app.use("/api", groupRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const error = new Error("Not found");
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
});
```

the above snippet is of my app.js file. And my route code looks somethig like this.

```
exports.groups_Get_All = (req, res, next) => {
    Group.find()
        .exec()
        .then(docs => {
            const response =
                docs.map(doc => {
                    return {
                        gname: doc.gname,
                        employee: doc.employeeId,
                        _id: doc._id,
                        createdAt: doc.createdAt
                    };
                })
            res.send((response));
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            });
        });
};
```

Right now im getting response of just plain data in json format.

```
[
    {
        "gname": "wordpres",
        "employee": [
            "5c6568102773231f0ac75303"
        ],
        "_id": "5c66b6453f04442603151887",
        "createdAt": "2019-02-15T12:53:25.699Z"
    },
    {
        "gname": "wordpress",
        "employee": [
            "5c6568102773231f0ac75303"
        ],
        "_id": "5c66cbcf1850402958e1793f",
        "createdAt": "2019-02-15T14:25:19.488Z"
    }
]
```

Now my question is how to implement this sample format response to every api(global scope)?

Comment: I use `res.end(JSON.stringify(results));`

Comment: it only stringify the data. it doesnt give in proper format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using express, don't send the message from the **controller**. Make a middleware that's main purpose is to send the response to the client. This will give you a power of setting the format of **consist** response to the client.

For Example I have made the response middleware like this :-

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  const message = {};
  message.body = req.responseObject;
  message.success = true;
  message.status = req.responseStatus || 200;
  res.status(message.status).send(message);
  return next();
};
```

Above code will generate the format like this.

```
{
  "success": true,
  "status": 200,
  "body": {
    "name": "rahul"
  }
}
```

You can use **request uplifter** property of express. You can add responseObject and responseStatus from previous middleware.

Errors can be made in separate middleware likewise.

You can call by this in your routes:-

```
const responseSender = require('./../middleware/responseSender');
 /* your rest middleware. and put responseSender middleware to the last.*/
router.get('/',/* Your middlewares */, responseSender);
```

You can call it by:-

```
exports.groups_Get_All = (req, res, next) => {
    Group.find()
        .exec()
        .then(docs => {
            const response =
                docs.map(doc => {
                    return {
                        gname: doc.gname,
                        employee: doc.employeeId,
                        _id: doc._id,
                        createdAt: doc.createdAt
                    };
                })

            req.responseObject = response; // This will suffice
            return next()
        })
        .catch(next);
}
```

Comment: how to call this middleware from every api?

Comment: please check the answer again. I have edited the answer.

Comment: after implementing your code snippet, i m getting {
    "success": true,
    "status": 200
} but not the data. I need to data to be displayed with this response.

Comment: You are sending the response two times. Send the response only once. **res.send()** should be called exactly once in your routes lifetime.

Comment: req.responseStatus = response; you mean req.responseObject ? Am i right?

Comment: message.status = req.responseStatus || 200;
  res.status(message.status).send(message); ---- if i give this , node ll take only 200 status code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188589/discussion-between-supermacy-and-darshan-a-n).