# express create standard JSON return format

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express

I'm new to express, currently if I want to send a response I would do the following

```js
//...
res.json({
  status: 200,
  message: "success",
  data: "something"
})
//...
```

for all my controllers functions I would do it this way. I guess this is kind of overwhelming so I was thinking if it's possible to make a generalized version of response.

so after some search I found there is 2 ways of achieving this:

### 1. use a middleware that runs at the end of each route

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54744128/proper-way-to-return-json-format-using-node-or-express). which made it clear but I think it's a waste of time and my controller then won't be readable enough and I must do the following in every controller function

```js
req.responseObject = response;
return next()
```

### 2. override response class of the express itself

this is much promising, but unfortunately after so many tries and following express docs I couldn't get it to work
here is what I've tried so far

I've created this util function here:

```js
//myRes.js
module.exports = function (code, message, payload) {
  return this.status(code).json({
    status: 'success',  // this will be variable according to whatever code I get
    code: code,
    message: message || '',
    payload: payload || '',
  });
};
```

then I've added this line to app.js

```js
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const myRes= require('./utils/myRes');
app.response.send = myRes;
//...
```

and this is how I use it on my controller

```js
res.send(200, "hello world", [{"key": "value"}])
```

when I try to run this I got this Error stack

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify ([project_dir]\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1123:12)
    at ServerResponse.json ([project_dir]\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:260:14)
    at ServerResponse.module.exports [as send] ([project_dir]\src\utils\response.js:2:28)
    at ServerResponse.json ([project_dir]\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.module.exports [as send] ([project_dir]\src\utils\response.js:2:28)
    at ServerResponse.json ([project_dir]\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.module.exports [as send] ([project_dir]\src\utils\response.js:2:28)
    at ServerResponse.json ([project_dir]\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.module.exports [as send] ([project_dir]\src\utils\response.js:2:28)
    at ServerResponse.json ([project_dir]\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.module.exports [as send] ([project_dir]\src\utils\response.js:2:28)
    at ServerResponse.json ([project_dir]\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.module.exports [as send] ([project_dir]\src\utils\response.js:2:28)
    at ServerResponse.json ([project_dir]\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.module.exports [as send] ([project_dir]\src\utils\response.js:2:28)
```

why JSON.stringify is complaining I haven't used this function on my entire application

also I am not just capped to these 2 solutions you can suggest other ways if you think it's better

Comment: This is not an answer to your question per se but you don't need "status" and "code" in your response, that should be handled by the protocol. Read https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-rest. Usually a success is returned with status code 200 and that should be enough.

Comment: this is just an example of what I am trying to do

Comment: Ok, the problem might be that ".json" actually calls ".send" making it a recursive call. https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/884e080a19015a81a46aef73792be12ad3220715/lib/response.js#L239-L267

Comment: Try modifyng "app.response.send = myRes;" to "app.response.customSend = myRes;" and calling that function instead

Comment: wow, that was really it. thanks for help

Comment: Don't forget to read the link I've pasted before. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

clarifying what @Ariel said in the comments

Express response calls send internally refer to this [function](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/884e080a19015a81a46aef73792be12ad3220715/lib/response.js#L107) from express at lines [120, 123, 136] and that was causing a infinite loop that's why it was saying

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

so all I needed to do is to change my function name from send to maybe "sends" and that just worked

it was a bad idea trying to overwrite the built in send function

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [responser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oY4d.png) npm package to accomplish just that.

It lets you choose any of the http status code as methods.

Turn a repetitive response standard like this:

```
router.get('/hello', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.status(400).json({
    status: 'BAD_REQUEST',
    code: 400,
    message: 'Request is wrong!',
    success: false
  })
})
```

into this:

```
router.get('/hello', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send_badRequest('Request is wrong!')
})
```

And both of the above will generate **exactly** the same output.

**Tip**: if you're using typescript, it will even show you all the available methods.

[image]