# axios DELETE method gives a 404 Not Found error

Tags: node.js, express, axios

In my MERN app, users can comment on photos. Comments are subdocuments in my Photos Mongoose model. I want to create a axios API that deletes a comment given a commentId and photoId.

Deleting a comment works just fine in Postman. So does my axios.post call to create a comment.

I suspect the issue is with my axios.delete call. The request hits my catch statement saying that the photo is not found, but the comment deletes just fine with the same data when I try on Postman. In ChromeDev tools, I get a 404 not found error.

[404 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkmWT.png)

[Specific error from catch statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSDUF.png)

```
server/routes/api/photos.js

// DELETE COMMENT (protected)

router.delete(
  "/comment/delete",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    let { commentId, photoId } = req.body;
    Photo.findOne({ _id: photoId })
      .then(photo => {
        photo.comments.pull({ _id: commentId });
        photo.save();
        res.json(photo.comments);
      })
      .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nophotofound: "No photo found" }));
  }
);
```

```
frontend/src/util/photo_api_util.js

import axios from "axios";

export const deletePhotoComment = data => {
  return axios.delete("/api/photos/comment/delete", data);

// ex: data = {photoId: "...", commentId: "..."}
};
```

Comment: I think your error is due to this line res.json({comments:photo.comment}); it has to be a json format.

Comment: Doesn't res.json specify it will be in json format?

Comment: No, it means that it sends a response with the parameter converted in a json string using JSON.stringify, hence it must have a json format.

Comment: According to this answer, res.json returns in json format: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23198978/9102483