# Cannot read property 'success' of null on angular 6

Tags: angular

**i keep getting this error on angular 6 have codes the backend now on connecting on registering the user he should be directed to the admin dashboard unfortunately  am getting that caoont be read the property of success is null while when i use another route  the pop up window  tells me undefined hellp me guys am to submit this assignment on Wednesday am newbie from tanzania**

````
core.js:6014 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of null
    at SafeSubscriber._next (login.component.ts:26)

Show 40 more framesHere is my login.components.ts```
````

**Here is my login.components**

````
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private Auth: AuthService,private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  loginUser(event)
  {
    event.preventDefault()
    const target = event.target
    const email= target.querySelector('#email').value
    const password = target.querySelector('#password').value


    this.Auth.loginUser(email, password).subscribe(data => {
      if(data.success)
      {
        //redirect the person to admin page
        this.router.navigate(['admindashboard'])
        this.Auth.setLoggedIn(true)


      }
      else
      {
        window.alert(data.message)
      }
      return false;
    });
    console.log(email, password)
  }

}```
````

**here is my auth.service.ts**

````
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{ HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

interface myData
{
  success:boolean,
  message: string
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  uri ='http://localhost:4000';

  private loggedInStatus = false
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  setLoggedIn(value: boolean)
  {
  this.loggedInStatus = value
  }

  get isLoggedIn()
  {
    return this.loggedInStatus
  }


  loginUser(email,password){
    return this.http.post<myData>(`${this.uri}/register`, {
      email,
      password
    });
  }


}```
````

*Here is my Api*

````
``` server.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {


     const { email, password } = req.body;

     const clearadmin = new Clearadmin({
         email,
         password
     });

     bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {

        bcrypt.hash(clearadmin.password, salt, async (err, hash) => {

            //Hash Password
            clearadmin.password = hash;

            //save clearadmin
            try{
               const newClearadmin = await clearadmin.save();
               res.send(201);
               next();
            }
            catch(err)
            {
             return next(new errors.InternalError(err.message));
            }
        });
     });
    });```
````

*My ClearAdmin Mongoose Schema*

````
const ClearAdminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email:
    {
        type:String,
        required:true,
        trim:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
});

const ClearAdmin = mongoose.model('ClearAdmin', ClearAdminSchema);
module.exports = ClearAdmin;```

    *the new Error am getting n my console now*

    ```Server started on port 4000
    (node:921) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot render headers after they are sent to the client
        at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:236:13)
        at ServerResponse.restifyWriteHead [as writeHead] (/Users/retina/ocapp/node_modules/restify/lib/response.js:632:25)
        at flush (/Users/retina/ocapp/node_modules/restify/lib/response.js:849:9)
        at ServerResponse.__send (/Users/retina/ocapp/node_modules/restify/lib/response.js:431:24)
        at ServerResponse.send (/Users/retina/ocapp/node_modules/restify/lib/response.js:316:21)
        at bcrypt.hash (/Users/retina/ocapp/routes/clearadmins.js:42:21)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    (node:921) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
    (node:921) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.```
````

Comment: Try to ```console.log(data)``` before ```if(data.success)```, what is it?

Comment: your api `${this.uri}/register` needs to return some result.It might be returning `null` currently

Comment: Using console.log(data) is not helping me @FatemeFazli

Comment: Please elaborate @jitender

Comment: check you api if it returns some data

Comment: @jitender please i have added my api check it on the above question and tell me wheat am missing it works fine on postman

Comment: you'r sending nothing in api  `res.send(201);` modify if to send json check out this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696240/proper-way-to-return-json-using-node-or-express

Comment: thanks @jitender have tried all the methods mentioned but am still getting null response on my chrome console

Comment: if you could tel me what exactly should i send to the response @jitender

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are not sending the user credentials the right way, email & password should be sent as a key-value JSON object in your service **auth.service.ts**. like this

```
loginUser(email,password){
    return this.http.post<myData>(`${this.uri}/register`, {
      email:email,
      password:password
    });
  }
```

Next, In your component **login.component.ts** you are trying to read the *success* property, while in your API, your response does not contain this property. Your API response should look like this.

```
res.status(201).json({
                        success:true,
                        msg:'registration successful'
                    })
```

And, In your API, I would suggest you to read the email & password in this way

```
const email = req.body.email;
const password = req.body.password;
```

Replace this

```
const clearadmin = new Clearadmin({
         email,
         password
     });
```

With this

```
const clearadmin = new Clearadmin({
         email:email,
         password:password
     });
```

Add the save method to your mongoose model, like this

```
const ClearAdminSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email:
    {
        type:String,
        required:true,
        trim:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    }
});

const ClearAdmin = modules.exports = mongoose.model('ClearAdmin', ClearAdminSchema);
//Save the user
module.exports.saveUser = function(newUser, callback){
    newUser.save(callback);
}
```

Now, make changes to your register route

```
server.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {

     const email = req.body.email;
     const password = req.body.password;

     const clearadmin = new Clearadmin({
         email:email,
         password:password
     });

     bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {

        bcrypt.hash(clearadmin.password, salt, async (err, hash) => {

            //Hash Password
            clearadmin.password = hash;

            //save clearadmin
            Clearadmin.saveUser(clearadmin,(err,registered)=>{
              if(err){
                  res.json({success:false, msg:'Error occurred at backend'})
              }if(registered){
                  res.json({success:true, msg:'user registered'})
              }
            })
        });
     });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks men but now am getting a pop up saying localhost:4200 says undefined

Comment: In your login.component.ts make changes to `window.alert(data.msg)` to read the msg property returned from backend and in your API return the json object with 'msg' for error in your catch block as well. Let me know if you don't know how to do that

Comment: Here is how your catch block should look like `catch(err){res.status(500).json({success:false,msg:'Failed to register'})}`

Comment: By doing this, if you receive a success:false, you will know that something is wrong with your API only and your Angular Front-end is good. If that's the case, I need to see more of your API code & what DB you are using.

Comment: thanks men i did now get my erros its says that UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot render headers after they are sent to the client please help me with this too

Comment: my api is up there am using mongoose db

Comment: Check the updated answer. If still there are errors, I need to see your Clearadmin mongoose model

Comment: i have just added it on the above question please check it out

Comment: but when i check the database it adds the new registred user the problem is it cant navigate to admindashboard

Comment: yes here is the error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot render headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: check the edit, I have created a save method in the mongoose model file and called that method from your register route. I have also removed the try catch with much elegant if else code

Comment: Let me know, if still there are any errors. If it resolves your issue, kindly mark this answer as accepted

Comment: am getting this error now TypeError: Clearadmin is not a constructor  const clearadmin = new Clearadmin({

Comment: have you imported your mongoose model file? eg. `const Clearadmin = require('path_to_models/clearadmin_model.js')`

Comment: yes i did check up the question i have posted all the errors showing in my console