# Getting HTML instead of JSON from NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, axios

I am working on project containing app and landing pages. We are using Nodejs with Axios and VueJs for app part. But for landing pages, it is simple jQuery. I must do some API calls for landing pages, but I am not able to use NodeJs result in jQuery to serve data in my landing pages. I am new at NodeJs and these technologies.
Here are my codes:

- my Routes :

  ```
  const router = express.Router();
  ...
  router.get('/api/items', myApiController.getItems);
  ```
- NodeJs controller

  ```
   module.exports.getItems = (req, res) => {
      const response = myApiController.getItems();

      if (response.status === 200) {
        res.send({
        status: 200,
        data: response.data
      })
    } else {
      res.send({
      status: 404,
      data: null
      })
    }
  }
  ```
- my main script :

  ```
  $.get("/api/items", function(data, status){
      alert("Data: " + data);
      var mylist = $("#mylist");
      $.each(data, function(item) {
        mylist.append($("<option />").val(item.name).text(item.name));
      });
  });
  ```

Even if I am getting status:200 the nodejs is returning HTML of page 404.
I do not find the cause, And honestly I do not understand the reason. It seems it is try to get a page does not exist, but I am requesting a json from function.
I try to replace contoller method call by a trash json but nothing work.
Here is what I try:

```
router.get('/api/items', function(req, res){
  console.log('cc');
  return res.json([{
    'toto': 'toto',
    'tata': 'tata',
  }]);
});
```

It seems routes definitions issue, but I do not know how to fix. Could this have something with express Router ? Could you please explain me and help me to fix this? Thanks

Comment: don't you specify `application/json` as the content type anywhere in your code?

Comment: I think we need the code for `myApiController.getItems` since it is returning a response object that you are using in your `if/then` to decide what to pass to `res.send()`

Comment: I dont think it is myApiController the problem. Can you check my last code part? I associate function to the router and the result is the same.

Comment: @user3788685 no, I am trying to do by the simple possible way. But as I said, I am new in this app architecture. Do you have any idea to how I can change things to get the list ? Thanks

Comment: @Cutis - check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696240/proper-way-to-return-json-using-node-or-express) question and answer it may help as we don't see enough of your code above

Comment: @user3788685 I have already checked it. that is not the same issue. thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you respond with a string, the content type will be HTML.  Try this, which removes the `res.json` call:

```
router.get('/api/items', function(req, res){
  console.log('cc');
  return [{
    'toto': 'toto',
    'tata': 'tata',
  }];
});
```

Comment: I do not know the difference with the last part of my code I pubish. But I try it and I am getting the same issue. What could be the issue?