# How to return JSON in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to node/express. I have a simple express app with one post route ('/'). Given a list of GitHub users names, it should return information about those developers.

For example, if I post

```
{ "developers": ["JohnSmith", "JaneDoe"] }
```

It should return

```
[
  {
    "bio": "Software Engineer at Google",
    "name": "John Smith"
  },
  {
    "bio": "Product Manager, Microsoft",
    "name": "Jane Doe"
  }
]
```

This is what I have so far

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    let results = req.body.developers.map(async d => {
      return await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${d}`);
    });
    let out = results.map(r => ({ name: r.data.name, bio: r.data.bio }));    
    return res.send(out);
  } catch {
    next(err);
  }
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.send("There was an error");
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Server started on port 3000!");
});
```

When I try this in a tool like Insomnia, I keep getting `There was an error`.

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use async await with Array.map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140149/use-async-await-with-array-map)

Comment: @EA6923 check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696240/proper-way-to-return-json-using-node-or-express

Comment: I think it is easy as res.send( JSON.stringify("There was an error"));

Comment: @user123456 that will result in `"\"There was an error\""` which is probably not what is desired.

Comment: @evolutionxbox he will always return res.send("There was an error");, he should terminate the response, he asked how do I return json, I think what he wants to know what is missing in his logic to return the formatted json he already gve

Answer (score 1):

The way you return JSON in an Express API is as follows:

```
res.status(200).json(out)
```

See https://expressjs.com/it/api.html for the full documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `res.formate()` as per [this](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.format) docs...

Or set type for `res` as per [this](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.type) Docs...

```
res.type('json')
```

Answer (score 0):

From middleware, you are always saying res.json("there is some error"), why are you keeping it there if not needed. if you remove app.use(). you will see the request is returning you names of the developer

read this for error handling.
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `There was an error`. Because, there is an error in your `/` route. But, the thing is you haven't wrote the `err` parameter with catch. If add that one in your `catch` (of your `try/catch` block) and `console.log` it, you'll see the error

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

You're getting this error because, `results` variable is actually an array of pending `Promise`. You need to first resolve these pending promises. One way to do is,

```js
app.post("/", function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const developers = req.body.developers;
    let promises = [];
    developers.map((d) => {
      promises.push(axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${d}`));
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then((responses) => {
      let out = responses.map((r) => ({
        name: r.data.name,
        bio: r.data.bio,
      }));

      return res.send(out);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```