# How to retrieve the particular data set from JSON file in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, json, express

Below you can see my user.json file

```
     [
       {
          "id":1,
          "name":"Jhone",
          "username":"Jhone123",
       },
       {
          "id":2,
          "name":"Ervin",
          "username":"Ervin123",
       },
       {
          "id":3,
          "name":"Bauch",
          "username":"Bauch123",
       },
       {
          "id":4,
          "name":"Lebsack",
          "username":"Lebsack123",
       },
       {
          "id":5,
          "name":"Kamren",
          "username":"Kamren123",
       }
    ]
```

Here is my Node.js Server

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080
var users = require('./users');

app.get('/user/:uid', (req, res) => {s
  let jsonString = JSON.stringify(users[0]);
  res.send(jsonString);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
  });
```

How do I send the data according to the uid?

Ex:
http://localhost:8080/user/uid=1

When I use uid=1, Output should be like below

```
 {
     "id":1,
      "name":"Jhone",
      "username":"Jhone123",
     }
```

Comment: use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search for the id

Comment: Hi ! Do you stuck on how to generate and send a (json) response, or how to read values in the user.json ?

Comment: @Philippe  I want to send a JSON response according to the particular id as my example. When we pass uid=1, I want to get the name and username of id=1

Comment: Ok ? @SamuelGoldenbaum gave you the way to find values in your json, and if needed, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19696240/4698373), it explains the best ways to send the answer :)

Comment: Thank you I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways to do this.

A simple example:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080
var users = require('./users');

app.get('/user/:uid', (req, res) => {
  let foundUser = users.find(x => x.id === parseInt(req.params.uid));
  let jsonString = JSON.stringify(foundUser);
  res.send(jsonString);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
  });
```

You can do similar things with the `Array.map()` function as well.