# PUT 404 (NOT FOUND) and SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript

[PUT 404 (NotFound) ][1]

[image]

Client-side code

```
const confirmDeliver = (event) => {
const newQuantity = inventory.quantity - 1;
const updateQuantity = { newQuantity };
const url = `http://localhost:5000/inventory/${inventoryId}`;
fetch(url, {
  method: "PUT",
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(updateQuantity),
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data)); };
```

Server-side code

```
   app.put("inventory/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const updatedQuantity = req.body;
  const filter = { _id: ObjectId(id) };
  const options = { upsert: true };
  const updatedDoc = {
    $set: {
      quantity: updatedQuantity.quantity,
    },
  };
  const result = await inventoryCollection.updateOne(
    filter,
    options,
    updatedDoc
  );
  res.send(result);
});
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error? How can I solve this?

Comment: How do you expect anyone to be able to tell you why that URL is giving a 404 error? You haven't shown any of the server side code that you expect to handle it.

Comment: In the image you got an error that say /inventory/{id} `PUT` not found. to catch that error add the .catch() closure to your code.

Comment: @Jackkobec — You suppose wrong. The error message shows the URL and the value is in it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your qeustion? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696240/proper-way-to-return-json-using-node-or-express

Comment: Typo: Your route path needs to be `app.put("/inventory/:id"`with a `/` at the front.

Answer (score -1):

‘Unexpected token <‘ means the response returned is not a valid json. This error may be from a 404 error html page responded from backend.

The request method PUT is different from request methods GET, POST. Make sure the backend has a PUT request method with an appropriate endpoint `http://localhost:5000/inventory/your-inventory-id`.

To fast test a SUCCESS connection to backend, simply code in backend to return an empty `{}` json response.