# Cannot extract key/value from json

Tags: javascript, json

A resource is fetched in node.js like this:

```
requestify.post('myurl')
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.body);
});
```

console.log(response) gives:

```
Response {
    code: 200,
    body: '{"guid":"abcd","nounce":"efgh"}' 
}
```

console.log(response.body) gives:

```
{"guid":"abcd","nounce":"efgh"}
```

However, for some reason I cannot access the key "guid" or "nounce". In both cases I get an undefined.
I have tried both with

```
console.log(response.body.guid);
```

and

```
console.log(response.body['guid']);
```

Comment: Can you tell me the type of `'{"guid":"abcd","nounce":"efgh"}' `?

Comment: you need to JSON.parse that JSON string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body is string, but you want it to be an object. Just transform it:

```
JSON.parse(response.body).guid
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the value of `body` property is a string. You must parse it as JSON:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(response.body).guid);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the return type to

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
```

so your receiving end will make it an object automagically when received.
See [Responding with a JSON object in NodeJS (converting object/array to JSON string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892569/responding-with-a-json-object-in-nodejs-converting-object-array-to-json-string)