# How to send JSON data back to client in vanilla Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to send json data to the client in Nodejs NOT using Express or any other frameworks. How is it possible to achieve ?

```
const server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    switch (request.url){
        case '/':
            mainPage(request, response);
            break;
        default:
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.end('Page not found');
    }
})

function mainPage(request, response){
    const clientData = {"status": "ok"}

    .... // send back to client, how ?
 }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Responding with a JSON object in Node.js (converting object/array to JSON string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892569/responding-with-a-json-object-in-node-js-converting-object-array-to-json-string)

Comment: Just set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`, then send the stringified json `JSON.stringify(data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write on the `response` object:

```
function mainPage(request, response) {
    const data = {"status": "ok"};
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
    response.end(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```